# Large number of subplots with matplotlib

Tags: python, graphics, plot, matplotlib, subplot

I would like to create plot with many (100) subplots with Python matplotlib. I cannot find appropriate syntax for it:

I would like something like (this is not working)

```
plt.subplot(10,10,i,X1, Y)
```

in a loop with i from 0 to 99, then

```
plt.show()
```

Syntax is available in many tutorials for case when there are only few subplots. Then, syntax can be

```
plt.close('all')
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = plt.subplot(221)
ax2 = plt.subplot(223)
ax3 = plt.subplot(122)

example_plot(ax1)
example_plot(ax2)
example_plot(ax3)

plt.tight_layout()
```

[code is from here](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html).

For my problem, I guess that I cannot use the same syntax, as I would have `plt.subplot(10101)`, etc., which I don't understand.

Do you have a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(10, 10)
```

where ax will contain one hundred axis in a list (of lists).

It is a really handy function, from [the docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots):

```
Definition: plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, sharex=False, sharey=False, squeeze=True, subplot_kw=None, **fig_kw)
Create a figure with a set of subplots already made.

This utility wrapper makes it convenient to create common layouts of
subplots, including the enclosing figure object, in a single call.
```

Answer (score 13):

Here's a fully working code solution that shows how things are numbered, since it looks like people still come to look here:

```
columns = 10
rows = 4
fig, ax_array = plt.subplots(rows, columns,squeeze=False)
for i,ax_row in enumerate(ax_array):
    for j,axes in enumerate(ax_row):
        axes.set_title('{},{}'.format(i,j))
        axes.set_yticklabels([])
        axes.set_xticklabels([])
#         axes.plot(you_data_goes_here,'r-')
plt.show()
```

Which outputs this to show you how the numbering works (I only did 4 row instead of 10 to make the picture a bit smaller, just change "rows" to 10 to get 10 rows of subplots):

### [image: Matplotlib array of subplots]

The numbering shows you what i and j values you'll have at each position so you can line things up the way you want in the array of matplotlib subplots. This incorporates subplotting in arrays for whatever layout you'd like.

Comment: I know this is ancient but if you set rows or columns to 1, the code fails because there is nothing to iterate over.

Comment: @Mr.Fegur - A fair enough point, although the whole point is showing a big array. Hopefully folks can see how to eliminate the unneeded loop if they want, do you want an example of that?

Comment: Perhaps editing your answer to include the squeeze='False' option in plt.subplots will make the answer handle the columns/row=1 case.

Comment: @Mr.Fegur - Added. I hadn't ever had the occasion to use that, thank you for pointing me at it. neat!

Comment: See here for having one colorscale for all the subplots: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar

Answer (score 10):

Your example is almost correct. Please use:

```
for i in range(100):
    ax = plt.subplot(10,10,i)
    ax.plot(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to generate ~100 subplots, as a practical matter you may want to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13060980/380231) which will run much faster.  You give up have individual axes labels, but with 100 subplots, unless you are making *huge* print outs you won't be able to read the labels anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example where you can choose the **number of rows** and **columns** to generate. In the example I generate random sine waves in random colors.

```
import numpy             as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cols = 5
rows = 20

x_data  = np.linspace(0,50,100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(40, 40), dpi=80)
for i in range(cols*rows):
    ax = plt.subplot(rows,cols,i+1)    
    ax.plot(x_data, random.uniform(0, 5)*np.sin(x_data+random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi)), 
            c= [random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1)])
```

[image: Image of the generated plot]