# How to have one colorbar for all subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, colorbar

I've spent entirely too long researching how to get two subplots to share the same y-axis with a single colorbar shared between the two in Matplotlib.

What was happening was that when I called the `colorbar()` function in either `subplot1` or `subplot2`, it would autoscale the plot such that the colorbar plus the plot would fit inside the 'subplot' bounding box, causing the two side-by-side plots to be two very different sizes.

To get around this, I tried to create a third subplot which I then hacked to render no plot with just a colorbar present. 
The only problem is, now the heights and widths of the two plots are uneven, and I can't figure out how to make it look okay.

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import division
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import patches
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter

# SIS Functions
TE = 1 # Einstein radius
g1 = lambda x,y: (TE/2) * (y**2-x**2)/((x**2+y**2)**(3/2)) 
g2 = lambda x,y: -1*TE*x*y / ((x**2+y**2)**(3/2))
kappa = lambda x,y: TE / (2*np.sqrt(x**2+y**2))

coords = np.linspace(-2,2,400)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(coords,coords)
g1out = g1(X,Y)
g2out = g2(X,Y)
kappaout = kappa(X,Y)
for i in range(len(coords)):
    for j in range(len(coords)):
        if np.sqrt(coords[i]**2+coords[j]**2) <= TE:
            g1out[i][j]=0
            g2out[i][j]=0

fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0,hspace=0)

# subplot number 1
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1,aspect='equal',xlim=[-2,2],ylim=[-2,2])
plt.title(r"$\gamma_{1}$",fontsize="18")
plt.xlabel(r"x ($\theta_{E}$)",fontsize="15")
plt.ylabel(r"y ($\theta_{E}$)",rotation='horizontal',fontsize="15")
plt.xticks([-2.0,-1.5,-1.0,-0.5,0,0.5,1.0,1.5])
plt.xticks([-2.0,-1.5,-1.0,-0.5,0,0.5,1.0,1.5])
plt.imshow(g1out,extent=(-2,2,-2,2))
plt.axhline(y=0,linewidth=2,color='k',linestyle="--")
plt.axvline(x=0,linewidth=2,color='k',linestyle="--")
e1 = patches.Ellipse((0,0),2,2,color='white')
ax1.add_patch(e1)

# subplot number 2
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2,sharey=ax1,xlim=[-2,2],ylim=[-2,2])
plt.title(r"$\gamma_{2}$",fontsize="18")
plt.xlabel(r"x ($\theta_{E}$)",fontsize="15")
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter( NullFormatter() )
plt.axhline(y=0,linewidth=2,color='k',linestyle="--")
plt.axvline(x=0,linewidth=2,color='k',linestyle="--")
plt.imshow(g2out,extent=(-2,2,-2,2))
e2 = patches.Ellipse((0,0),2,2,color='white')
ax2.add_patch(e2)

# subplot for colorbar
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax3.axis('off')
cbar = plt.colorbar(ax=ax2)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 431, accepted):

Just place the colorbar in its own axis and use `subplots_adjust` to make room for it.

As a quick example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
for ax in axes.flat:
    im = ax.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)), vmin=0, vmax=1)

fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.15, 0.05, 0.7])
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that the color range will be set by the last image plotted (that gave rise to `im`) even if the range of values is set by `vmin` and `vmax`. If another plot has, for example, a higher max value, points with higher values than the max of `im` will show in uniform color.

Comment: ImageGrid is also very useful for this exact purpose.

Comment: if you need to use tight_layout(), you will want to do everything after subplots_adjust after tight_layout, and then tweak the coordinates for subplots_adjust and add_axes manually.

Comment: How can I have a single color bar for two different scatter plots that I already have? I tried above but I don't know how to substitute "im" with appropriate variables. Let say my scatter plots are plot1=pylib.scatter(x,y,z) and plot2=pylib.scatter(a,b,c)

Comment: How do you do this if you need to loop over a dataset to generate the individual plots? e.g. I'd have `for i in range(4):; subplot(2,2,i); plot(data[i])` - how does that work with the axes loop?

Comment: This may have been obvious to others, but I wanted to point out that in order that the colourbar does accurately represent the colour in all the plots, the `vmin` and `vmax` arguments are critical. They control the colour range of each subplot. If you have real data, you may need to do a pass through this to find the min and max values first.

Comment: @kungfujam How would you set the `vmin` and `vmax` parameters in this case? The `colorbar` method doesn't support these 2 parameters.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai they are arguments for `imshow` method, not `colorbar`. In the answer they are set to 0 and 1. 

Another handy tip for `imshow` here is to set the argument `interpolation='none'` so the plot is not blurred. [See here for examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html)

Comment: I thought it was possible to set a color bar for multiple subplots that don't have the same range of values (mine were all different), so I just decided to have multiple color bars.

Comment: if the range of values of the plots is different, the colorbar range would only show the last plot's range, right? any suggestions?

Comment: @JamesOwers : as per the [imshow docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html), `interpolation=None` is already the default.

Comment: @pas-calc the default is indeed `None` which then [defaults to `antialiased`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html#interpolations-for-imshow). Still need to specify `interpolation="none"` for no interpolation.

Answer (score 232):

You can simplify Joe Kington's code using the `ax`parameter of `figure.colorbar()` with a list of axes.
From [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=colorbar#matplotlib.figure.Figure.colorbar):

> ax
>
> > None | parent axes object(s) from which space for a new colorbar axes will be stolen. If a list of axes is given they will all be resized to make room for the colorbar axes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
for ax in axes.flat:
    im = ax.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)), vmin=0, vmax=1)

fig.colorbar(im, ax=axes.ravel().tolist())

plt.show()
```

[image: 1]

Comment: This solution worked very well here, and seems to be the easiest one.

Comment: If you change nrows to 1, both plots are shoter than colorbar. so, how can solve this problem?

Comment: Pity it doesn't work with tight_layout, but good solution nonetheless.

Comment: Just to remember... I love this solution! Tinha que ser cearense!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The colorbar is on top of the right column in a 2x2 configuration

Comment: I have the same problem as Bensge. How does one fix this?

Comment: The crucial part of this answer is `fig.colorbar(im, ax=axes.ravel().tolist())`. If you omit `ax=axes.ravel().tolist()`, the colorbar will be placed within one subplot.

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer and, most importantly, to many other people with different problems: _"How does one fix this?"_ Post a new question where ① you reference the answer that is not working for you, ② you show your code and the results you've got, ③ you compare those results with your expectations.

Comment: @Mark The answer works with `fig = plt.figure(..., constrained_layout=True)` ፨ in general using `constrained_layout` provides results similar to the use of `plt.tight_layout()` but  simply better and more reliable.

Comment: @gboffi Oh that's good to know, it seems to be experimental for now and didn't exist back in 2016, but seems like a good improvement.

Comment: In matplotlib 3.6.1 (and maybe before), you can just use `ax=axs` instead of `ax=axs.ravel().tolist()`.

Comment: I wonder why no one has mentioned it so far, but one has to be careful with this answer. Tthe colorbar drawn by this solution only covers the data range of the last plot. i.e., if the min/max of other subplots are beyond the min/max of the very last one, they will be shown "saturated". This may not be the intended behavior when sharing colorbar across subplots.

Answer (score 77):

This solution does not require manual tweaking of axes locations or colorbar size, works with multi-row *and* single-row layouts, and works with `tight_layout()`.  It is adapted from a [gallery example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_axes_grid2.html), using `ImageGrid` from matplotlib's [AxesGrid Toolbox](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid

# Set up figure and image grid
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9.75, 3))

grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,          # as in plt.subplot(111)
                 nrows_ncols=(1,3),
                 axes_pad=0.15,
                 share_all=True,
                 cbar_location="right",
                 cbar_mode="single",
                 cbar_size="7%",
                 cbar_pad=0.15,
                 )

# Add data to image grid
for ax in grid:
    im = ax.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)), vmin=0, vmax=1)

# Colorbar
ax.cax.colorbar(im)
ax.cax.toggle_label(True)

#plt.tight_layout()    # Works, but may still require rect paramater to keep colorbar labels visible
plt.show()
```

[image: image grid]

Comment: Double +1, this is a great approach

Comment: Indeed works with tight_layout, but I have no idea how to add a label to that colorbar. It doesn't accept the kws label, title, text... anything! And the docs don't help much.

Comment: @TomCho To set a label, you can grab the colorbar's handle when you instantiate it, as: `thecb = ax.cax.colorbar(im)`. Then you can do `thecb.set_label_text("foo")`

Comment: @Chiel The `rect` parameter specifies the bounding box of the figure elements with the figure area. It takes normalized figure co-ords and the default is `[0,0,1,1]`. So specifying `rect=[0,0,0.9,1]` as an argument to `tight_layout` would force the figure elements that tight_layout knows about to fit within 90% of the figure width, leaving 10% for your label. See [doc](https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html).

Comment: How to change the colormap?

Comment: I think this is the most complete, yet simple solution.

Comment: @Sigur I am sure you have figured it out by now, but for others, you can change the cmap when declaring im:

im = ax.imshow(data, vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap='your_cmap_here')

Comment: Hi! I really like this answer. After updating matplotlib, I get this warning: 'MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
  The mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.colorbar module was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.2 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use matplotlib.colorbar instead.' However, I didn't figure out how to replace these lines now: `ax.cax.colorbar(im)
ax.cax.toggle_label(True)`

Comment: @all Just in case anyone is interested, I found a solution: Replace the line `ax.cax.colorbar(im)` by `ax.cax.cla()` `matplotlib.colorbar.Colorbar(ax.cax,im)`. Of course, `matplotlib.colorbar` must be imported in the beginning. In case anyone wants to suppress the labels of the colorbar, use `ax.cax.toggle_label(False)` and add `ax.cax.tick_params(size=0)`.

Answer (score 43):

Using `make_axes` is even easier and gives a better result. It also provides possibilities to customise the positioning of the colorbar.
Also note the option of `subplots` to share x and y axes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
for ax in axes.flat:
    im = ax.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)), vmin=0, vmax=1)

cax,kw = mpl.colorbar.make_axes([ax for ax in axes.flat])
plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax, **kw)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This method does not work when the subplot is not square. If you change `nrows=1`, the colorbar becomes larger than the subplots again.

Comment: What's your matplotlib defaults? it looks great!

Comment: Unfortunately this is also incompatible with the use of tight_layout too...

Answer (score 36):

## Shared colormap *and* colorbar

This is for the more complex case where the values are not just between 0 and 1; the cmap needs to be shared instead of just using the last one.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
cmap = cm.get_cmap('viridis')
normalizer = Normalize(0, 4)
im = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=normalizer)
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
    ax.imshow(i + np.random.random((10, 10)), cmap=cmap, norm=normalizer)
    ax.set_title(str(i))
fig.colorbar(im, ax=axes.ravel().tolist())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, but in order to use colormaps other than viridis you need to add `cmap=cmap` to the creation of the `ScalarMappable`. It should read `im=cm.ScalarMappable(norm=normalizer, cmap=cmap)`

Comment: For me this code throws, `TypeError: You must first set_array for mappable`

Answer (score 31):

As a beginner who stumbled across this thread, I'd like to add a python-for-dummies adaptation of **abevieiramota**'s very neat answer (because I'm at the level that I had to look up 'ravel' to work out what their code was doing):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ((ax1,ax2,ax3),(ax4,ax5,ax6)) = plt.subplots(2,3)

axlist = [ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5,ax6]

first = ax1.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)), vmin=0, vmax=1)
third = ax3.imshow(np.random.random((12,12)), vmin=0, vmax=1)

fig.colorbar(first, ax=axlist)

plt.show()
```

Much less pythonic, much easier for noobs like me to see what's actually happening here.

Answer (score 26):

### New in matplotlib 3.4.0

Shared colorbars can now be implemented using **subfigures:**

> New [`Figure.subfigures`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subfigures) and [`Figure.add_subfigure`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subfigure) allow ... **localized figure artists (e.g., colorbars** and suptitles) that only pertain to each subfigure.

The matplotlib gallery includes demos on [how to plot subfigures](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subfigures.html).

Here is a minimal example with 2 subfigures, each with a shared colorbar:

[image: subfigure colorbars]

```py
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
(subfig_l, subfig_r) = fig.subfigures(nrows=1, ncols=2)

axes_l = subfig_l.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharey=True)
for ax in axes_l:
    im = ax.imshow(np.random.random((10, 10)), vmin=0, vmax=1)

# shared colorbar for left subfigure
subfig_l.colorbar(im, ax=axes_l, location='bottom')

axes_r = subfig_r.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, sharex=True)
for ax in axes_r:
    mesh = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.randn(30, 30), vmin=-2.5, vmax=2.5)

# shared colorbar for right subfigure
subfig_r.colorbar(mesh, ax=axes_r)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the cleanest and simplest solution, IMO.

Answer (score 25):

As pointed out in other answers, the idea is usually to define an axes for the colorbar to reside in. There are various ways of doing so; one that hasn't been mentionned yet would be to directly specify the colorbar axes at subplot creation with `plt.subplots()`. The advantage is that the axes position does not need to be manually set and in all cases with automatic aspect the colorbar will be exactly the same height as the subplots. Even in many cases where images are used the result will be satisfying as shown below.

When using `plt.subplots()`, the use of `gridspec_kw` argument allows to make the colorbar axes much smaller than the other axes.

```
fig, (ax, ax2, cax) = plt.subplots(ncols=3,figsize=(5.5,3), 
                  gridspec_kw={"width_ratios":[1,1, 0.05]})
```

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

fig, (ax, ax2, cax) = plt.subplots(ncols=3,figsize=(5.5,3), 
                  gridspec_kw={"width_ratios":[1,1, 0.05]})
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3)
im  = ax.imshow(np.random.rand(11,8), vmin=0, vmax=1)
im2 = ax2.imshow(np.random.rand(11,8), vmin=0, vmax=1)
ax.set_ylabel("y label")

fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

This works well, if the plots' aspect is autoscaled or the images are shrunk due to their aspect in the width direction (as in the above). If, however, the images are wider then high, the result would look as follows, which might be undesired.

[image]

A solution to **fix the colorbar height to the subplot height** would be to use `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.InsetPosition` to set the colorbar axes relative to the image subplot axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import InsetPosition

fig, (ax, ax2, cax) = plt.subplots(ncols=3,figsize=(7,3), 
                  gridspec_kw={"width_ratios":[1,1, 0.05]})
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3)
im  = ax.imshow(np.random.rand(11,16), vmin=0, vmax=1)
im2 = ax2.imshow(np.random.rand(11,16), vmin=0, vmax=1)
ax.set_ylabel("y label")

ip = InsetPosition(ax2, [1.05,0,0.05,1]) 
cax.set_axes_locator(ip)

fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax, ax=[ax,ax2])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm allowed to ask this here, but is there a way to implement this solution using `ax = fig.add_subplot()` instead? I'm asking because I can't figure out how to use it with basemap.

Comment: @lanadaquenada Yes that is possible, but you would need to supply a `GridSpec` to `add_subplot()` in that case.

Answer (score 13):

The solution of using a list of axes by **abevieiramota** works very well until you use only one row of images, as pointed out in the comments.  Using a reasonable aspect ratio for `figsize` helps, but is still far from perfect.  For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(9.75, 3))
for ax in axes.flat:
    im = ax.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)), vmin=0, vmax=1)

fig.colorbar(im, ax=axes.ravel().tolist())

plt.show()
```

[image: 1 x 3 image array]

The [colorbar function](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar) provides the `shrink` parameter which is a scaling factor for the size of the colorbar axes.  It does require some manual trial and error.  For example:

```
fig.colorbar(im, ax=axes.ravel().tolist(), shrink=0.75)
```

[image: 1 x 3 image array with shrunk colorbar]

Answer (score 11):

To add to @abevieiramota's excellent answer, you can get the euqivalent of tight_layout with constrained_layout.  You will still get large horizontal gaps if you use `imshow` instead of `pcolormesh` because of the 1:1 aspect ratio imposed by `imshow`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, constrained_layout=True)
for ax in axes.flat:
    im = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.random((10,10)), vmin=0, vmax=1)

fig.colorbar(im, ax=axes.flat)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This topic is well covered but I still would like to propose another approach in a *slightly* different philosophy.

It is a bit more complex to set-up but it allow (in my opinion) a bit more flexibility. For example, one can play with the respective ratios of each subplots / colorbar:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

# Define number of rows and columns you want in your figure
nrow = 2
ncol = 3

# Make a new figure
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)

# Design your figure properties
widths = [3,4,5,1]
gs = GridSpec(nrow, ncol + 1, figure=fig, width_ratios=widths)

# Fill your figure with desired plots
axes = []
for i in range(nrow):
    for j in range(ncol):
        axes.append(fig.add_subplot(gs[i, j]))
        im = axes[-1].pcolormesh(np.random.random((10,10)))

# Shared colorbar    
axes.append(fig.add_subplot(gs[:, ncol]))
fig.colorbar(im, cax=axes[-1])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I noticed that almost every solution posted involved `ax.imshow(im, ...)` and did not normalize the colors displayed to the colorbar for the multiple subfigures. The `im` mappable is taken from the last instance, but what if the values of the multiple `im`-s are different? (I'm assuming these mappables are treated in the same way that the contour-sets and surface-sets are treated.) I have an example using a 3d surface plot below that creates two colorbars for a 2x2 subplot (one colorbar per one row). Although the question asks explicitly for a different arrangement, I think the example helps clarify some things. I haven't found a way to do this using `plt.subplots(...)` yet because of the 3D axes unfortunately.

[image: Example Plot]

If only I could position the colorbars in a better way... (There is probably a much better way to do this, but at least it should be not too difficult to follow.)

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

cmap = 'plasma'
ncontours = 5

def get_data(row, col):
    """ get X, Y, Z, and plot number of subplot
        Z > 0 for top row, Z < 0 for bottom row """
    if row == 0:
        x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10, dtype=int)
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, x)
        Z = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
        if col == 0:
            pnum = 1
        else:
            pnum = 2
    elif row == 1:
        x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10, dtype=int)
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, x)
        Z = -np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
        if col == 0:
            pnum = 3
        else:
            pnum = 4
    print("\nPNUM: {}, Zmin = {}, Zmax = {}\n".format(pnum, np.min(Z), np.max(Z)))
    return X, Y, Z, pnum

fig = plt.figure()
nrows, ncols = 2, 2
zz = []
axes = []
for row in range(nrows):
    for col in range(ncols):
        X, Y, Z, pnum = get_data(row, col)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, pnum, projection='3d')
        ax.set_title('row = {}, col = {}'.format(row, col))
        fhandle = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cmap)
        zz.append(Z)
        axes.append(ax)

## get full range of Z data as flat list for top and bottom rows
zz_top = zz[0].reshape(-1).tolist() + zz[1].reshape(-1).tolist()
zz_btm = zz[2].reshape(-1).tolist() + zz[3].reshape(-1).tolist()
## get top and bottom axes
ax_top = [axes[0], axes[1]]
ax_btm = [axes[2], axes[3]]
## normalize colors to minimum and maximum values of dataset
norm_top = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(zz_top), vmax=max(zz_top))
norm_btm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(zz_btm), vmax=max(zz_btm))
cmap = cm.get_cmap(cmap, ncontours) # number of colors on colorbar
mtop = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm_top)
mbtm = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm_btm)
for m in (mtop, mbtm):
    m.set_array([])

# ## create cax to draw colorbar in
# cax_top = fig.add_axes([0.9, 0.55, 0.05, 0.4])
# cax_btm = fig.add_axes([0.9, 0.05, 0.05, 0.4])
cbar_top = fig.colorbar(mtop, ax=ax_top, orientation='vertical', shrink=0.75, pad=0.2) #, cax=cax_top)
cbar_top.set_ticks(np.linspace(min(zz_top), max(zz_top), ncontours))
cbar_btm = fig.colorbar(mbtm, ax=ax_btm, orientation='vertical', shrink=0.75, pad=0.2) #, cax=cax_btm)
cbar_btm.set_ticks(np.linspace(min(zz_btm), max(zz_btm), ncontours))

plt.show()
plt.close(fig)
## orientation of colorbar = 'horizontal' if done by column
```

Comment: If the values from the multiple `im`s are different, they should *not* use the same colorbar, so the original question wouldn't really apply

Answer (score 5):

The answers above are great, but most of them use the `fig.colobar()` method applied to a `fig` object. This example shows how to use the `plt.colobar()` function, applied directly to `pyplot`:

```
def shared_colorbar_example():
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3)
    for ax in axs.flat:
        plt.sca(ax)
        color = np.random.random((10))
        plt.scatter(range(10), range(10), c=color, cmap='viridis', vmin=0, vmax=1)
    plt.colorbar(ax=axs.ravel().tolist(), shrink=0.6)
    plt.show()

shared_colorbar_example()
```

Since most answers above demonstrated usage on 2D matrices, I went with a simple scatter plot. The `shrink` keyword is optional and resizes the colorbar.

If `vmin` and `vmax` are not specified this approach will automatically analyze all of the subplots for the minimum and maximum value to be used on the colorbar. The above approaches when using `fig.colorbar(im)` scan only the image passed as argument for min and max values of the colorbar.

Result:

[image: Result of running the code snippet above]