# get QuadMesh object from Axes (or Figure)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a plot where the various subplots all share a colorbar similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar).  The problem that I'm running into is that in my script, I'm calling a function which creates the `QuadMesh` (generated from [`ax.pcolormesh`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh)) instance and returns the `Figure` and `Axes` instances associated with it.  Is there any way to get a handle on the QuadMesh instance from the Axes instance (or Figure instance)?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def foo(subplot):
    data = np.random.random((100,100))
    x,y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(101),np.arange(101))
    fig = plt.gcf()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(subplot)
    quadmesh = ax.pcolormesh(x,y,data)
    return fig,ax

fig = plt.figure()
f,a = foo(221)
f,a = foo(222)
f,a = foo(223)
f,a = foo(224)
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.85,0.15,0.05,0.7])
#fig.colorbar(magic_get_quadmesh,cax=cbar_ax)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not really sure this is what you want -- especially since there are 4 quadmeshes -- but you can find the quadmesh given the AxesSubplot via its `collections` attribute:

```
fig.colorbar(a.collections[0], cax=cbar_ax)
```

---

By the way, I found the answer using this exploratory introspection tool:

```
def describe(obj):
    for key in dir(obj):
        try:
            val = getattr(obj, key)
        except AttributeError:
            continue
        if callable(val):
            help(val)
        else:
            print('{k} => {v!r}'.format(k=key, v=val))
        print('-' * 80)
describe(a)
```

Yeah, it prints out *a lot* of output, but a quick search for `"quadmesh"` leads you to the answer.

Comment: That's exactly what I want.  Since all of the quadmeshes need to share the same colorbar, they're all actually created with the same arguments passed to `quadmesh.set_clim`.  So, as long as I have a handle on one of the quadmesh objects, I can create the colorbar I want.  Will accept in 5 min or so :)

Comment: Oh nice.  I looked through the output of `dir`, but didn't find anything off the bat ... so I thought I'd post a question here.  (maybe it'll help someone else someday)