# Add colorbar to scatter plot or change the plot type

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting some data that includes spatial (x, y) components as well as a z component, which is the value of the measurement at that point in space. I was looking at the gallery, and I'm just not *getting* it. I think that what I want is a pcolormesh, but I don't understand what I need to put in for arguments. I finally had success getting a scatter plot to do basically what I want, but it's less pretty than I want. If I could figure out a way to make the points in the scatter plot bigger, I would be a lot happier with my plot. Furthermore, I am stuck on trying to add a legend - I only need the colorbar portion, since the end user doesn't really care about the X and Y dimensions. Looking at the colorbar example, it seems that I need to add an axis, but I don't understand how I'm telling it that the axis I need is the Z axis.

```
x_vals = list(first_array[data_loc_dictionary['x_coord_index']][:])
y_vals = list(first_array[data_loc_dictionary['y_coord_index']][:])
y_vals = [-i for i in y_vals]
z_vals = list(first_array[data_loc_dictionary['value_index']][:])

plt.scatter(x_vals, y_vals, s = len(x_vals)^2, c = z_vals, cmap = 'rainbow')
plt.show()
```

Here is an example of what I am trying to duplicate:
[image]
And here is what the code above produces:
[image]

- I would like the second to look a little more like the first, i.e., if there were a way to adjust the markers to be large enough to approximate that look, that would be ideal
- I am struggling with creating a legend. Colorbar seems to be the way to go, but I am not comprehending how to specify that it needs to be based on the Z values.

Good catch with the ^2 - 
[image]

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting a question out of that. What exactly is your question? What kind of graph is appropriate for your data?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682216/scatter-plot-and-color-mapping-in-python/17682382#17682382

Comment: Also, by `len(x_vals)^2`, do you mean `len(x_vals)**2`?  Right now you are doing `len(x_vals) XOR 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this basic example:

```
# generate random data
In [63]: x = np.random.rand(20)
In [64]: y = np.random.rand(20)
In [65]: z = np.random.rand(20)

# plot it with square markers: marker='s'
In [66]: plt.scatter(x, y, s=len(x)**2, c=z, cmap='rainbow', marker='s')
Out[66]: <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x39e6c90>

# colorbar
In [67]: c = plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal')
In [68]: c.set_label('This is a colorbar')
In [69]: plt.show()
```

[image]

The Size of the points is given by

```
s : scalar or array_like, shape (n, ), optional, default: 20

    size in points^2.
```

I see no reason why `s=len(x)**2` is a good choice by default.  I would play around with it according to your preference.

Comment: Thanks! Silly me, of course it knows what data corresponds to the colorbar. The additional arguments in the examples I'd seen were confusing me.

Comment: @mauve Try using `marker='s'` in your scatter to make squares.

Comment: There's no reason it has to be squares. Circles are actually preferable. On this particular plot, I'd love it if I could force the circles to only overlap if the distance between the centers is smaller than 9mm.

Comment: @mauve What do you mean by "the distance between the centers is smaller than 9mm"? To change the point size, adjust `s` in `plt.scatter`.

Comment: Thanks! The example from MatPlotLib had the len(x)**2 in it, which is where I got it. I didn't play with it. I've settled on s = max(x_values). I'll probably adjust that later. On to the next issue!

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to know how to replicate your initial example image with pcolormesh, I would do:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 5))
grid = np.arange(-5, 6)
x, y = np.meshgrid(grid, grid)

z = np.random.randn(len(x), len(y)) 
mask = (np.abs(x) + np.abs(y)) > 4
z = np.ma.masked_array(z, mask)

mesh = ax.pcolormesh(x - .5, y - .5, z, cmap="coolwarm", vmin=-3, vmax=3)
plt.colorbar(mesh)
```

To produce:

[image]