# why my scatter plot shows no color?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot, jupyter-notebook

I am working on scattering plot using matplotlib and just simply testing 
  several sample codes, but cannot show colors. Only showing gray.
  For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
t = np.arange(100)

plt.scatter(x, y, c=t)
plt.show()
```

This is the exactly same as [this previous question about scatterplots and color mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682216/scatter-plot-and-color-mapping-in-python). See the execution result:

[image: Screenshot of results]

What's wrong with my setup?
   I am using Jupyter python 3.x version.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236566/setting-different-color-for-each-series-in-scatter-plot-on-matplotlib

Comment: It works for me with Python 2.7

Comment: It works for me too (Python 2.7)

Comment: It shows colors to me. The question is why should it work? To set colors you should pass tuples of three. To set gray you should set a number between 0 and 1, but pass it as a string. So that command `c=t` is not really clear to me. Try `cmap=plt.cm.hot` inside the scatter command.  It could be that you have `cm.gray` set earlier, and need to refresh the kernel.

Comment: Thank you! Using 'cmap=plt.cm.hot' and 'camp = pt.cm.jet both' work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to force a specific colormap:

```
plt.scatter(x, y, c=t, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
```

Also, as a bonus, you could colorize it more:

```
plt.scatter(x, y, c=t, cmap=plt.cm.jet,
            s=30, linewidths=0, alpha=0.7)  # "s" is for (marker)"size"
```

I cannot properly "test" it because your original code works for me.