# plotting using color as a gradient in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, colors

I am new to visualization in python. I am trying to plot the same dataset on the left but by using colors as gradient and gridlines to make it understandable. But I'm stuck and I don't know what I did, I just used the reference codes I got from other similar questions. Can someone help out?

```
import random
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from matplotlib import colors
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np

style.use('ggplot')
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

def update(val):
    pos = s_time.val
    ax.axis([pos, pos+10, 20, 40])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

def plot():
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,root)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill = tk.BOTH, expand =1)
    
    fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

    y_values = [random.randrange(41) for _ in range(40)]
    x_values = [i for i in range(40)]

    ax.axis([0, 9, 20, 40])
    ax.plot(x_values, y_values)

    #cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['red', 'blue','green'])
    #bounds = [0,10,20,30]
    #norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
    #ax1.imshow(ax, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
    im0  = ax1.pcolormesh([x_values,y_values], vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap="RdBu")
    im = fig.colorbar(im0,cax=ax1)
    ax1.grid(which='major', axis='both', linestyle='-', color='white', linewidth=0.5)

    #ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 40, 2.5))

    ax_time = fig.add_axes([0.12, 0.1, 0.78, 0.03])
    return ax_time
    

root = tk.Tk()
fig = plt.Figure(figsize = (10,10),dpi = 150)
ax=fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1=fig.add_subplot(122)
s_time = Slider(plot(), 'Time', 0, 30, valinit=0)
s_time.on_changed(update)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The question is not clear and your code doesn’t work.  Please specify what you mean by “using colors…to make it understandable”.

Comment: I want to make a grid and the points I have given should be plotted on the grid with certain colors. Something like this, https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/pcolor_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-pcolor-demo-py

Comment: suggest you look at https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/pcolormesh_levels.html instead of that `pcolor` example.  You need, x, y, and a 2-D matrix Z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: Not sure if I understood the question correctly. Maybe you could provide links to the reference questions.

If you want to add a color gradient to a lineplot in matplotlib, to my knowledge the best bet is to use `ax.scatter`. A similar question was asked here:
[Matplotlib: different color for every point of line plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623731/matplotlib-different-color-for-every-point-of-line-plot)
To mimic the appearance of a lineplot you need to interpolate your data linearly before passing it to the scatter function. The `c` keyword argument can be used to assign a color-value to each data point and the cmap argument determines the actual mapping from color-value to color.

Here is a minimally working example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
y_values = np.random.randint(0, 41, size=40)
x_values = np.arange(0, 40, 1)

x_interp = np.arange(0, 40, 0.01)
y_interp = np.interp(x_interp, x_values, y_values)
ax.grid(alpha=0.5)
artist = ax.scatter(x_interp, y_interp, c=y_interp, cmap='seismic', lw=0)
f.colorbar(artist, ax=ax)
```

Which yields the following [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPjrZ.png)

**EDIT**:
After clarification I interpret the question as:
"How do I add a background to a lineplot, that shows a color gradient corresponding to the values on the y-axis".

My suggestion is the following:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
f, a  = plt.subplots(1, 1)

value_range = (vmin, vmax) = (0, 40)
x_range = (xmin, xmax) = (0, 60)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(range(xmin, xmax, 1), range(vmin, vmax, 1))
y_data = np.random.randint(vmin, vmax, size=xmax-xmin)
x_data = np.arange(xmin, xmax, 1)

a.pcolormesh(Y, cmap="seismic", alpha=0.5, edgecolors='gray')
a.plot(x_data, y_data, "k-")
```

Which then yields the following [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFi3E.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This is similar to what I asked for but I meant colors on a grid
Reference graph(Which I want it to look like): https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/pcolor_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-pcolor-demo-py

Comment: If this answers your question, do you mind accepting it as the answer?