# Matplotlib color assignment error?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I'm trying to make a colorful scatter plot based on data in an array:

```
plt.scatter(150, 93, c=y_pred)
```

Here, `y_pred` is:

```
array([ 5,  6,  8, 16, 21, 12, 12, 13,  6,  6, 17, 11,  6, 12, 12, 23,  6,
        6, 15,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6, 23, 22,  6, 12, 17,  6, 20,  0,  6,
        6, 12, 12,  0,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  5, 17,  6,  6, 11, 10, 13,
        6, 22, 24, 23,  6,  6, 13,  6,  6,  6, 12,  9, 15, 13, 14,  6, 18,
        1,  6,  9,  6,  6, 11,  6,  5, 16,  9, 23,  2, 14, 24,  9,  5,  9,
       10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  1,  6, 19,  6, 23,  3,
       20, 10,  4,  8,  9,  6,  6,  9, 22, 23,  6,  6, 11,  6,  6,  6, 22,
       24, 14,  4,  7, 12,  6, 19,  6, 12,  3, 22,  6, 11,  6, 21, 23,  4,
        6,  6,  6,  4, 10, 22, 15,  6,  6, 18,  6, 14,  4,  5], dtype=int32)
```

This gives me an error:

> ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 17

I don't understand why. The same solution works for [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682216/scatter-plot-and-color-mapping-in-python). Could you help me understand the error?

Answer (score 1):

You only add one scatter point at `x=150 ; y=93` but you try to assign 150 colors for this one value.

```
plt.scatter(150, 93)
```

[image]

It works if you pass in `x` and `y` that have the same shape as `c`:

```
plt.scatter(np.random.random(150), np.random.random(150), c=y_pred)
```

[image]