# XY plot with heat type weights

Tags: python

I am working on some mini project. I have array of x,y and want to connect all xy pairs with a number corresponding it's weight (like a heat map or sth). List of position is X,y pairs while the list of weights is list of numbers. My code look like this:

```
def plot_data(layer_num):
    t = list_of_postitions[layer_num]
    c = list_of_weights[layer_num]
    # we create matrix of x,y positions of spots
    r = np.reshape(t,(-1,2))
    print(np.shape(r))
    x, y = r.T
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.title('Layer {}'.format(layer_num))
    plt.xlabel("X position")
    plt.ylabel("Y position")
    plt.show()
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Could you give an example of what the data looks like?

Comment: Its and array of points like [x1,y1,x2,y2,...] and wieght is [w1,w2,w3,...]

Comment: Please provide a working snippet with some test data - it will be far easier for us to help you.

Comment: I have the answer for my problem right now but thank you very much for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [pyplot documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html), you could use `s` parameter to change size of each point (if you want the plot size correspond to the weight) or `c` parameter to adapt color (there is tutorial that explain how to use it, one example [here](https://www.science-emergence.com/Articles/How-to-create-a-scatter-plot-with-several-colors-in-matplotlib-/)).

Both of `s` and `c` parameter could be an array with same length of position `x` and `y`.

Comment: Np additional info: for the size it's easy, just `plt.scatter(x, y, s=c)`. I wrote `c` because i saw in your code this is how you call your 'list_of_weights'. 

For color, it's a little bit tricky as you have to use a [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html). Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682216/scatter-plot-and-color-mapping-in-python) too

Comment: it works like a charm even doing c=c but the diferences between weights are very little so i see very little change of color. Is there and option to nromalize it better automaticaly?

Comment: `plt.scatter(x, y, c=c, cmap='viridis')` should be ok. If I well remember, the colormap will fit with your min/max `c` values. You can use other registered colormap name instead of 'viridis'.

Comment: thank you Sir for your help. Now I can continue my project :)