# pandas df columns series

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Have dataframe, and I have done some operations with its columns as follows

```
df1=sample_data.sort_values("Population")
df2=df1[(df1.Population > 500000) & (df1.Population < 1000000)]
df3=df2["Avg check"]*df2["Avg Daily Rides Last Week"]/df2["CAC"]
df4=df2["Avg check"]*df2["Avg Daily Rides Last Week"]
([[df3],[df4]])
```

If I understand right, then df3 & df4 now are series only, not dataframe. There should be a way to make a new dataframe with these Series and to plot scatter. Please advise. Thanks.

Wanted to add annotate for each and faced the issue

```
df3=df2["Avg check"]*df2["Avg Daily Rides Last Week"]/df2["CAC"]
df4=df2["Avg check"]*df2["Avg Daily Rides Last Week"]
df5=df2["Population"]
df6=df2["city_id"]
sct=plt.scatter(df5,df4,c=df3, cmap="viridis")
plt.xlabel("Population")
plt.ylabel("Avg check x Avg Daily Rides")
for i, txt in enumerate(df6):
plt.annotate(txt,(df4[i],df5[i]))
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can pass both `Series` to [`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sc = plt.scatter(df3, df4)
```

EDIT: Swap `df5` and `df4` and for select by positions use [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
for i, txt in enumerate(df6):
    plt.annotate(txt,(df5.iat[i],df4.iat[i]))
```

Comment: Many thanks! What if I need to add the label to identify dots + somewhat colormap to add one more metric ?

Comment: @EvgenyPetrov - You are welcome, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682216/scatter-plot-and-color-mapping-in-python)

Comment: Many thanks. Would it be possible to see what's wrong with annotate function in my code ?

Comment: @EvgenyPetrov - what is your code? Can you edit question, or better create new one?

Comment: Could not include the code in this comment block and added in the main content above

Comment: @EvgenyPetrov - there was swapped `df5` and `df4`, also added `iat` for select by positions, edited answer.

Comment: Thanks !  so iat is somewhat like a function from the library that I have missed ?

Comment: @EvgenyPetrov - exactly, added to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DataFrame from Series. [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-a-dataframe-from-pandas-series/) is how to do it. Simply add both series in a dictionary

```
author = ['Jitender', 'Purnima', 'Arpit', 'Jyoti'] 
article = [210, 211, 114, 178] 

auth_series = pd.Series(author) 
article_series = pd.Series(article) 

frame = { 'Author': auth_series, 'Article': article_series }
```

and then create a DataFrame from that dictionary:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(frame)
```

The code is from geeksforgeeks.org