# Scatter points with colormap for increasing indices

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

How do you color the scatter points based on their index? For instance, I would like points with smaller indices to have a lighter colour of the `Blues` colormap and the ones with larger indices to have a darker colour.

```
from numpy.random import randn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


points = randn(20, 2)
plt.scatter(*points.T)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scatter plot and Color mapping in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682216/scatter-plot-and-color-mapping-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this one

```
x = range(20)
plt.scatter(x, x, c=x, cmap=plt.get_cmap('Blues'))
```

It seems you can just pass the indices to `c` argument