# Adding a colorbar to two subplots with equal aspect ratios

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to add a colorbar to a plot consisting of two subplots with equal aspect ratios, i.e. with `set_aspect('equal')`:

[image]

The code used to create this plot can be found in [this IPython notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/dawehner/example-notebooks/blob/master/Untitled4.ipynb).

The image created using the code shown below ([and here in the notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/dawehner/example-notebooks/blob/master/Untitled4.ipynb#Try-to-setup-a-separate-axes-for-the-colorbar)) is the best result I could get, but it is still not quite what I want.

```
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.pcolormesh(rand1)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.pcolormesh(rand2)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')

plt.tight_layout()

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
divider = make_axes_locatable(plt.gca())
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)

plt.colorbar(cax=cax)
```

[image]

This question seems related:

- [Matplotlib 2 Subplots, 1 Colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Well, it is jsut displayed bad :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. Also, what do you mean with "Well it is just displayed bad"?

Comment: It's not very helpful if you post code, which is not self-contained, don't show the outcome and don't describe what you expect. How are people supposed to help you?

Comment: I am sorry, but my browser had serious issues to download images yesterday. Updated the initial comment to contain a link to the published notebook.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm still not sure what you exactly want but I guess you want to subplots using `pcolormesh` to have the same size when you add a colorbar?

What I have now is a bit of a hack as I add a `colorbar` for both subplots to ensure they have the same size. Afterwords I remove the first `colorbar`. If the result is what you want I can look into a more pythonic way of achieving it. For now it is still a bit vague as to what you exactly want.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable


data = numpy.random.random((10, 10))

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1, aspect = "equal")
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2, aspect = "equal")

im1 = ax1.pcolormesh(data)
im2 = ax2.pcolormesh(data)

divider1 = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
cax1 = divider1.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)

divider2 = make_axes_locatable(ax2)
cax2 = divider2.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)

#Create and remove the colorbar for the first subplot
cbar1 = fig.colorbar(im1, cax = cax1)
fig.delaxes(fig.axes[2])

#Create second colorbar
cbar2 = fig.colorbar(im2, cax = cax2)

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the solution to my problem. I tried to document my previous approach as well as your solution on http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/dawehner/38146566287fb23def4a

Answer (score 4):

This solution is similar to the one above, but does not require creating and discarding the colorbar.

Notice that there is a potential flaw in both solutions: the colorbar will use the colormap and normalization of one of the color meshes. If these are the same for both, it is not a problem.

The [`ImageGrid` class](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html) has something that looks like what you want:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
fig = plt.figure(1, (4., 4.))
ax = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)

cm = plt.pcolormesh(rand1)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="100%", pad=0.4)
plt.pcolormesh(rand2)
cax.set_aspect('equal')

sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.cmap, norm=cm.norm)
sm._A = []

cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="10%", pad=0.1)
plt.colorbar(sm, cax=cax)
None # Prevent text output
```

Comment: I disagree on the comment you made about the potential flaw. When using one `colorbar` for two subplots created using `pcolormesh` or `imshow`, etc, the `vmin` and `vmax` of both datasets must be identical. Otherwise you would not even be allowed to use a single colorbar. In the case that `vmin` and `vmax` do differ you need to use two `colorbars` which you can both normalize individually.

Comment: A cleaner (I'll let you judge, it is a matter of taste to some extend) is to put a semi-colon at the end of the last line (i.e. using `plt.colorbar(sm, cax=cax);`)

Answer (score 1):

Although the accepted solution works, it is rather hacky. I think a cleaner approach is to use GridSpec. It also scales better to larger grids.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

nb_cols = 5
data = numpy.random.random((10, 10))

fig = plt.figure()
gs = matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec(1, nb_cols)        
axes = [fig.add_subplot(gs[0, col], aspect="equal") for col in range(nb_cols)]

for col, ax in enumerate(axes):
    im = ax.pcolormesh(data, vmin=data.min(), vmax=data.max())
    if col > 0:
        ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

fig.colorbar(im, ax=axes, pad=0.01, shrink=0.23)
```

[image]