# matplotlib subplots in a column with common horizontal colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have seen those nice solutions for making multiple subplots maintaining the aspect ratio "equal" of each subplot:

[Matplotlib 2 Subplots, 1 Colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13784201/10659110)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23953487/10659110

...but with a different geometry.
I wave 3 "square" plots (3 colormaps with the same x and y ranges) and I want to arrange them in a vertical column, with a single horizontal colorbar at the top or bottom.

Here an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from pylab import meshgrid,cm,imshow,contour,clabel,colorbar,axis,title,show

Nlatt  = 200 
Lrange = 20  

# Create grid values first.
xs = np.linspace(-Lrange, Lrange, Nlatt,  endpoint=True)
ys = np.linspace(-Lrange, Lrange, Nlatt , endpoint=True)
X,Y = meshgrid(xs, ys)         # grid of point

Zx = np.sin(Y-X)*np.sin(Y+X)
Zy = np.cos(Y)*np.sin(X)
ZZ = np.sqrt( Zx**2 + Zy**2 )

fig = plt.figure()  #e.g. "2,3,4" means "2x3 grid, 4th subplot"
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,1, aspect = "equal")
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,2, aspect = "equal")
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,3, aspect = "equal")

im1 = ax1.pcolor( X , Y , Zx , cmap='bwr' ,vmin=-2.5, vmax=2.5)
im2 = ax2.pcolor( X , Y , Zy , cmap='bwr' ,vmin=-2.5, vmax=2.5)
im3 = ax3.pcolor( X , Y , ZZ , cmap='bwr' ,vmin=-2.5, vmax=2.5)

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

I want to add the common horizontal colorbar at the top (or at the bottom) and share the x-axis, so that the label "x" and the x-coordinate numbers appear only on the bottom of the third plot. in practice, the desired output is the one described in [Matplotlib shared horizontal colorbar aligned with bottom axis in subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49638108/10659110) , but it is not very clear to me how this solution works. Moreover, I also want a single label and numbers for the x-axis at the bottom. Thank you for every hint.