# matplotlib colorbar and histogram with shared axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to display a 2D `np.array` with `imshow` and the respective colorbar which should share its axis with a histogram of the `np.array`. Here is an attempt, however, without shared axes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,10))

data = np.random.normal(0, 0.2, size=(100,100))
cax = ax.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.jet)

divider = make_axes_locatable(plt.gca())
axBar = divider.append_axes("bottom", '5%', pad='7%')
axHist = divider.append_axes("bottom", '30%', pad='7%')

cbar = plt.colorbar(cax, cax=axBar, orientation='horizontal')
axHist.hist(np.ndarray.flatten(data), bins=50)

plt.show()
```

I tried to use the `sharex` argument in `axHist` with `axHist = divider.append_axes("bottom", '30%', pad='7%', sharex=axBar)` but this somehow shifts the histogram data:[image]

Besides the shared axis x, how could one modify the histogram to take the same colors as the colormap, similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608731/how-to-add-colorbar-to-a-histogram)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may color every patch of histogram by bin value without sharex:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,10))

data = np.random.normal(0, 0.2, size=(100,100))
cax = ax.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.jet)

divider = make_axes_locatable(plt.gca())
axBar = divider.append_axes("bottom", '5%', pad='7%')
axHist = divider.append_axes("bottom", '30%', pad='7%')

cbar = plt.colorbar(cax, cax=axBar, orientation='horizontal')

# get hist data
N, bins, patches = axHist.hist(np.ndarray.flatten(data), bins=50)

norm = Normalize(bins.min(), bins.max())
# set a color for every bar (patch) according 
# to bin value from normalized min-max interval
for bin, patch in zip(bins, patches):
    color = cm.jet(norm(bin))
    patch.set_facecolor(color)

plt.show()
```

[image]

For more information look for manual page: https://matplotlib.org/xkcd/examples/pylab_examples/hist_colormapped.html

Comment: Great! I solved the shared axis issue by adding `plt.xlim(data.min(), data.max())` just below the line `N, bins, patches ...` Maybe you could also add this to the answer.

Comment: You may post your variant as a new answer.