# Make matplotlib.pyplot color bar span two rows alongside waveform and specgram

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, colorbar

Using matplotlib.pyplot, I have two plots.  One is a waveform of an audio file.  The second is a spectrogram  of the same audio.  I want the wave form to be directly above the spectrogram (same x-axis, and aligned together).  I also want a colorbar for the spectrogram.

Problem - when I put the colorbar in, it attaches to the spectrogram row and the waveform extends over the colorbar (i.e. is no longer time-aligned with the spectrogram and is wider than the spectrogram).

I am close to the solution, I think, but I just can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong or what to change to get it working the way I want.  Hope someone can point me in the right direction!

Using the following python code (I made the code as MWE as possible):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from scipy.io import wavfile
from matplotlib import mlab
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib import stride_tricks

samplerate, data = wavfile.read('FILENAME.wav')

times = np.arange(len(data))/float(samplerate)

plt.close("all")

####
#Waveform
####
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(13.6, 7.68))

plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(times, data, color='k') 

plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.xlim(times[0], times[-1])

max_amp = max(abs(np.amin(data)), abs(np.amax(data)))
min_amp = (max_amp * -1) - abs(np.amin(data) - np.amax(data))/50
max_amp = max_amp + abs(np.amin(data) - np.amax(data))/50

plt.ylim(min_amp, max_amp)

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_yticks(np.array([min_amp, min_amp/2, 0, max_amp/2, max_amp]))

ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')

ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')

ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(pad=115)

####
#Spectrogram
####

Fs = 5000*2.#10000.
NFFT = min(512, len(data))
noverlap = NFFT / 2
pad_to = NFFT * 16
dynamicRange = 27.5
vmin = 20*np.log10(np.max(data)) - dynamicRange

cmap = plt.get_cmap('inferno')

plt.subplot(212)
Pxx, freqs, times, cax = plt.specgram(data, NFFT=NFFT, Fs=samplerate, noverlap=noverlap, mode='magnitude', scale='dB', vmin=vmin, pad_to=pad_to, cmap=cmap)

axes_spec = plt.gca()
axes_spec.set_xlim([0., max(times)])
axes_spec.set_ylim([0, 5000])

plt.xlabel("Time (s)")
plt.ylabel("Frequency (hz)")

plt.colorbar(cax, label='(dB)').ax.yaxis.set_label_position('left')


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I can get the following plot:

[image: Waveform above spectrogram plus colorbar]

Making these slight modifications below, I can get the plot to look *almost* how I want.  The problem is, it creates a blank figure next to the colorbar.  This version, minus the blank figure, is what I am trying to create.

```
#Replace this for waveform
plt.subplot(221)
#Replace this for spectrogram
plt.subplot(223)
#Add this before colorbar
plt.subplot(122)
```

New version of plot:

[image: Waveform above spectrogram - both next to blank figure plus colorbar]

EDIT: There is another possibility that I am also OK with (or perhaps both, for good measure!)
[image: Waveform above spectrogram plus colorbar (but waveform/spectrogram are time-aligned)]

Comment: Have you seen these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar

Comment: Yes, but I could not figure out how to adapt that to this situation.  I have made many attempts to incorporate similar things from the web and questions here but the spectrogram gets me a bit confused on how to incorporate it with another non-spectrogram.

Comment: When I attempt the method provided in the answer to that link, @pablo-reyes, then I get this image: [two plots overlapping the color bar](http://imgur.com/a/uT9C3)

Comment: You might need to modify the right margin. You can use fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75). You can also shrink the colorbar. See an example below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example of colorbar based on one of the answers in [matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar). The parameter `pad` in `fig.colorbar` is used to specify the space between the plots and the colorbar, and `aspect` is used to specify the aspect ratio between the height and width of the colorbar. Specgram outputs the image as the 4th output parameter, so I'm using that for the colorbar.

```
fig,axs = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=2 )
N=1000; fs=10e3
x = np.sin(np.arange(N))+np.random.random(N)
spectrum, freqs, t, im = axs[1].specgram(x,Fs=fs,
                    cmap=matplotlib.cm.inferno,noverlap=255)
axs[0].plot(np.arange(0,N)/fs,x,'-');
axs[0].set_xlim(t[0],t[-1]);axs[1].set_xlim(t[0],t[-1])
axcb = fig.colorbar(im, ax=axs.ravel().tolist(), pad=0.04, aspect = 30)
```

[image]

It is important to notice that when `fig.colorbar` function is called using the `ax` parameter, the original plots will be resized to make room for the `colorbar`. If it is only applied to one of the plots, only that axis will be resized. Se below:

```
fig,axs = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=2 )
N=1000; fs=10e3
x = np.sin(np.arange(N))+np.random.random(N)
spectrum, freqs, t, im = axs[1].specgram(x,Fs=fs,
                    cmap=matplotlib.cm.inferno,noverlap=255)
axs[0].plot(np.arange(0,N)/fs,x,'-')
axs[0].set_xlim(t[0],t[-1]);axs[1].set_xlim(t[0],t[-1])
axcb = fig.colorbar(im, ax=axs[1], pad=0.04, aspect = 30)
```

[image]

Below it is shown a way of controlling the resizing of your original axes in order to make room for a colorbar using `fig.colorbar` with the `cax` parameter that will not resize further your original plots. This approach requires to manually make some room for your colorbar specifying the `right` parameter inside the function `fig.subplots_adjust` :

```
fig,axs = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=2 )
N=1000; fs=10e3
x = np.sin(np.arange(N))+np.random.random(N)
spectrum, freqs, t, im = axs[1].specgram(x,Fs=fs,
                    cmap=matplotlib.cm.inferno,noverlap=255)
axs[0].plot(np.arange(0,N)/fs,x,'-')
axs[0].set_xlim(t[0],t[-1]);axs[1].set_xlim(t[0],t[-1])
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.85)  # making some room for cbar
# getting the lower left (x0,y0) and upper right (x1,y1) corners:
[[x10,y10],[x11,y11]] = axs[1].get_position().get_points()
pad = 0.01; width = 0.02
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([x11+pad, y10, width, y11-y10])
axcb = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax)
```

[image]

And doing the same to span two rows by reading coordinates of the original two plots:

```
fig,axs = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=2 )
N=1000; fs=10e3
x = np.sin(np.arange(N))+np.random.random(N)
spectrum, freqs, t, im = axs[1].specgram(x,Fs=fs,
                    cmap=matplotlib.cm.inferno,noverlap=255)
axs[0].plot(np.arange(0,N)/fs,x,'-')
axs[0].set_xlim(t[0],t[-1]);axs[1].set_xlim(t[0],t[-1])
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.85)  # making some room for cbar
# getting the lower left (x0,y0) and upper right (x1,y1) corners:
[[x00,y00],[x01,y01]] = axs[0].get_position().get_points()
[[x10,y10],[x11,y11]] = axs[1].get_position().get_points()
pad = 0.01; width = 0.02
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([x11+pad, y10, width, y01-y10])
axcb = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks very similar to what's in the link.  It's great for generated/random data, but I still don't see how this can be easily adapted to the spectrogram case.  I really need to see and example of this with `specgram` to be convinced it's adaptable.  I also found a good way to do it using `matplotlib.GridSpec` - it's not a huge amount of extra code, but more than this answer, granted.  The `GridSpec` method also allows for switching between a full colorbar to only on the side of the spectrogram.  I would be really interested to see if this method can handle both these things!

Comment: I used to use `GridSpec`. I used to allocate some space for the colorbar that way too. But now I like less lines of code, so here is a solution also using specgram's image output (first time `specgram` user. I will use this in my research now). I put some sinusoidal signal too.

Comment: Yeah, I am definitely not opposed to less code!  Can your edit also be modified to limit the colorbar's height to a spectrogram?  If so, could you include both examples?

Comment: First off - I realized that `GridSpec` was actually unused in my answer.  Sorry that I brought it up erroneously.  I should have been focused on `subplot2grid()`, which is one extra piece from your answer.  This is because of the issue of having the colorbar span multiple rows, the only way that I can figure it out is by using something like `cbax = matplotlib.pyplot.subplot2grid((nrow, ncol), (cur_row, cur_col), rowspan=2, colspan=1)` and using `cbax` in the `fig.colorbar()` call and specifying `cax=cbax`.  This just puts me back at the answer I posted, for the colorbar height flexibility.

Comment: Treating a colorbar as another figure in a grid of columns and rows is very flexible indeed. I just wanted to explore other possibilities too in case I needed or someone else in the future. I have included a code that retrieves the coordinates of the axes corners and use that to place colorbars.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help!  It was the resizing of the colorbar that really got me stuck for your original answer.  I knew it had its own axis, but didn't realize it could be used for resizing (rather than just customizing the ticks, values, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I came up with is `subplot2grid()` function. This requies the use of `subplots`, which I was not using originally.  Following this method, I needed to change everything from using `plt` (`matplotlib.pyplot`) to using the axes for the given plot for each `.plot()` or `.specgram()` invocation.  The relevant changes are included here:

```
#No rows or columns need to be specified, because this is handled within a the `subplot2grid()` details
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(13.6, 7.68))

#Setup for waveform
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 60), (0, 0), rowspan=1,  colspan=56)
####WAVEFORM PLOTTING

#Setup for spectrogram
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 60), (1, 0), rowspan=1,  colspan=56)
####SPECTROGRAM PLOTTING

#Setup for colorbar
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 60), (0, 59), rowspan=1, colspan=1)
cbar = plt.colorbar(cax, cax=ax3, ax=ax2)
```

And a MWE bringing it all together:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use("TkAgg")
from scipy.io import wavfile
from matplotlib import mlab
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib import stride_tricks

samplerate, data = wavfile.read('FILENAME.wav')

times = np.arange(len(data))/float(samplerate)

plt.close("all")

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(13.6, 7.68))#nrows=2, ncols=2, 

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 60)

####
#Waveform
####
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 60), (0, 0), rowspan=1,  colspan=56)
ax1.plot(times, data, color='k')

ax1.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')

####
#Spectrogram
####
maxFrequency = 5000
Fs = maxFrequency*2.#10000.
NFFT = min(512, len(data))
noverlap = NFFT / 2
pad_to = NFFT * 16
dynamicRange = 27.5
vmin = 20*np.log10(np.max(data)) - dynamicRange

cmap = plt.get_cmap('inferno')

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 60), (1, 0), rowspan=1,  colspan=56)
Pxx, freqs, times, cax = ax2.specgram(data, NFFT=NFFT, Fs=samplerate, noverlap=noverlap, mode='magnitude', scale='dB', vmin=vmin, pad_to=pad_to, cmap=cmap)

ax2.set_ylim([0, maxFrequency])
ax2.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
ax2.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')

####
#Colorbar (for spectrogram)
####
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 60), (1, 59), rowspan=1, colspan=1)
cbar = plt.colorbar(cax, cax=ax3, ax=ax2)
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(pad=3, left='off', right='off', labelleft='on', labelright='off')

plt.show()
```

Here's an example of the output from this MWE:

[image: Waveform above spectrogram plus colorbar on right side (of both)]

Best part!  You need only change the `0` to `1` and the `rowspan` to be `1` in this line (i.e. :)

```
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 60), (1, 59), rowspan=1, colspan=1)
```

to make the colorbar span only the height of the spectrogram.  Meaning that changing between the two options is incredibly simple.  Here's an example of the output from this change:

[image: Waveform above spectrogram plus colorbar on right side (of spectrogram only)]

EDIT: GridSpec actually was unused, and so I edited it out.  The only relevant details that I needed involved calling `subplot2grid()` to set up the subplots.