# matplotlib Colormap in a lineplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I want to plot a couple of figures with several lines. Each line is asocciated with certain parameter (and a corresponding color) and i want to put a colorbar that shows the corresponding range of the parameter.

I found this question but in my case there is more than one plot ...

Here is an example code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

my_map = plt.cm.spectral

c = np.arange(10)

colors = [my_map(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, len(c))]
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=my_map,norm=plt.Normalize(np.min(c),np.max(c)))
sm._A = []

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)    

for i in range(len(c)):

    c0 = c[i]
    ax1.plot(c,c+c0,color=colors[i])

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)    

for i in range(len(c)):

     c0 = c[i]
     ax2.plot(c,c+c0,color=colors[i])

fig.colorbar(sm)


plt.show()
plt.close()
```

I'm almost there but i need to move the colorbar (create an axis ? )

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I don't reallt get what you want to do with the colorbar, care to explain more?

Comment: i want the colorbar to belong to both subfigures. 
I was thinking maybe is easier to put the bar horizontal

Comment: Check this then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar

Comment: Im not using imshow. With what i replace the the 'im' variable ?

Comment: you can use your `sm`: `fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.15, 0.05, 0.7])
fig.colorbar(sm, cax=cbar_ax)`

Comment: Well that would do indeed (i dont understant but woks). 

Thanks

Comment: no problem! I think the answer in the linked question has a reasonable explanation, I'd recommend reading that and a little bit of matplotlib's documentation on colorbar cax paramater.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar can you please either mark as duplicate or provide an answer. Providing answers in the comments is not useful because it prevents questions from being answered and solved such that they will stay unsolved forever.