# Colorbar for each row in ImageGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, datagrid, colorbar

Disclaimer:  I am very inexperienced using matplotlib and python in general.

Here is the figure I'm trying to make:

[image: almost complete figure]

Using `GridSpec` works well for laying out the plots, but when I try to include a colorbar on the right of each row, it changes the size of the corresponding subplot.  This seems to be a well known and unavoidable problem with `GridSpec`.  So at the advice of this question: [Matplotlib 2 Subplots, 1 Colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar?rq=1)
I've decided to remake the whole plot using `ImageGrid`. Unfortunately the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html) only lists  the options `cbar_mode=[None|single|each]` whereas I want 1 colobar per row.  Is there a way to do this inside a single `ImageGrid`? or will I have to make 2 grids and deal with the nightmare of alignment.

What about the 5th plot at the bottom? Is there a way to include that in the image grid somehow?

The only way I can see this working is to somehow nest two `ImageGrid`s into a `GridSpec` in a 1x3 column.  this seems overly complicated and difficult so I don't want to build that script until I know its the right way to go.

Thanks for any help/advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.  It seems `ImageGrid` uses `subplot` somehow inside it.  So I was able to generate the following plot using something like

```
TopGrid = ImageGrid( fig, 311,
                nrows_ncols=(1,2),
                axes_pad=0,
                share_all=True,
                cbar_location="right",
                cbar_mode="single",
                cbar_size="3%",
                cbar_pad=0.0,
                cbar_set_cax=True
                )  
<Plotting commands for the top row of plots and colorbar>

BotGrid = ImageGrid( fig, 312,
                nrows_ncols=(1,2),
                axes_pad=0,
                share_all=True,
                cbar_location="right",
                cbar_mode="single",
                cbar_size="3%",
                cbar_pad=0.0,
                )
<Plotting commands for bottom row . . .>
StemPlot = plt.subplot(313)
<plotting commands for bottom stem plot>
```

[image]

EDIT:  the whitespace in the color plots is intentional, not some artifact from adding the colorbars

Comment: Do you want the whitespace above and below the plots in the top two rows, or did that come along with the colorbars?

Comment: yes, thanks for clarifying.  The whitespace is intentional and encodes useful information about the plots, it is not an artifact from the colobars

Comment: What a great solution. Certainly worth more than a meagre +1 .