# ImageGrid with colorbars only on some subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I'm using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38940369/4506929) to set up 3x3 grid on which to plot my data. I chose this method specifically because it works with `tight_layout()`.

However, I'm reading the docs on the [AxesGrid](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html) toolkit and I can't figure out how to put colorbars only on the rightmost plots.

So far this is what I have:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid

letters='abcdefghi'
f1=plt.figure(figsize=(9,9))
grid = ImageGrid(f1, 111,
                nrows_ncols=(3,3),
                axes_pad=0.05,
                share_all=True,
                cbar_location="right",
                cbar_mode="each",
                cbar_size="2%",
                cbar_pad=0.15)

A=np.random.rand(10,10)

for i,axis in enumerate(grid):
    im=axis.imshow(A)
    axis.annotate(s=letters[i], xy=(0.1, .85), xycoords='axes fraction', bbox=dict(boxstyle="square", fc="w", alpha=0.9))
    if i in (2,5,8):
        axis.cax.colorbar(im)
f1.tight_layout()
f1.savefig('example.png')
```

Which produces this figure:

[image: figure]

Which is obviously not right, since every subplot has its own colorbar, even though it's not colored. I'm looking to have only `c`, `f` and `i` with colorbars that should be different. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to modify your `ImageGrid`. You set `cbar_mode` to `each` therefore all images have own colorbar set it to `edge` and set the direction to `row` (one colorbar for one row of images):

```
grid = ImageGrid(f1, 111,
                nrows_ncols=(3,3),
                axes_pad=0.05,
                share_all=True,
                cbar_location="right",
                cbar_mode='edge',
                direction = 'row',
                cbar_size="2%",
                cbar_pad=0.15)
```

[image]

To show colorbar with all labels I a little bit expand your figure `f1=plt.figure(figsize=(9.5,9))`

There is an example for edge colorbars in matplotlib tutorial: https://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_edge_colorbar.html

Comment: That was pretty simple. I wonder why that isn't in the [AxesGrid](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html) docs. Nowhere in that page there is the word "edge".