# colorbar within a loop with matshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I basically want to add a colorbar at each of the subplots in the code below ([link to code](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neural_networks/plot_mnist_filters.html) ). My attempts add all color bars at the end of the loop in the last subplot.

```
print(__doc__)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

mnist = fetch_mldata("MNIST original")
# rescale the data, use the traditional train/test split
X, y = mnist.data / 255., mnist.target
X_train, X_test = X[:60000], X[60000:]
y_train, y_test = y[:60000], y[60000:]

# mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(100, 100), max_iter=400, alpha=1e-4,
#                     solver='sgd', verbose=10, tol=1e-4, random_state=1)
mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(50,), max_iter=10, alpha=1e-4,
                solver='sgd', verbose=10, tol=1e-4, random_state=1,
                learning_rate_init=.1)

mlp.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("Training set score: %f" % mlp.score(X_train, y_train))
print("Test set score: %f" % mlp.score(X_test, y_test))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 4)
# use global min / max to ensure all weights are shown on the same scale
vmin, vmax = mlp.coefs_[0].min(), mlp.coefs_[0].max()
for coef, ax in zip(mlp.coefs_[0].T, axes.ravel()):
ax.matshow(coef.reshape(28, 28), cmap=plt.cm.gray, vmin=.5 * vmin,
           vmax=.5 * vmax)
ax.set_xticks(())
ax.set_yticks(())

plt.show()
```

**UPDATE:**
based on the link in the comment below, here is the code which adds the colorbar at the right of the diagram

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 4)
# use global min / max to ensure all weights are shown on the same scale
vmin, vmax = mlp.coefs_[0].min(), mlp.coefs_[0].max()
for coef, ax in zip(mlp.coefs_[0].T, axes.ravel()):
    im = ax.matshow(coef.reshape(28, 28), cmap=plt.cm.gray, vmin=.5 * vmin, vmax=.5 * vmax)
    ax.set_xticks(())
    ax.set_yticks(())

fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.15, 0.05, 0.7])
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax)

plt.show()
```

Comment: The code does not show any attempt to place the colorbar. Also, there are a lot of questions on SO about placing the colorbar, but the question does not state in how far they have not helped. E.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar?rq=1).

Comment: I didn't include my attempt to add the colorbar because it was wrong. But thanks for the link, it does exactly what I need. I'll update my question with the code to add the colorbar.