# Matplotlib, one colorbar for all subplots, overlay on papersize

Tags: python, matplotlib, overlay, subplot, colorbar

I´ve got the following problem, that my colorbar overlays my papersized subplots that are "printed" as an pdf.

Code example:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':

    titles = np.random.uniform(low=1, high=11, size=(1,10))
    temp = np.random.uniform(low=23, high=200, size=(10,10))
    ctf0102 = np.random.uniform(low=23, high=200, size=(10,10))
    ctf03 = np.random.uniform(low=23, high=200, size=(10,10))

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11.69,8.27), dpi=100)

    for num in range(len(titles)):

        ax = fig.add_subplot(3,4,num)

        im = ax.scatter(ctf03[1:,num], ctf0102[:,num], 12, temp[:,num], cmap='magma')

        ax.set_title(titles[num])


    fig.text(0.5, -0.00, '...', ha='center', fontsize=16)

    fig.text(-0.00, 0.5, '...', va='center', rotation='vertical', fontsize=16)

    cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.15, 0.05, 0.7])
    fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax)

    plt.tight_layout(pad=2)

    fig.savefig("example.pdf", dpi=fig.dpi, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.3)
```

[image]

Any idea how i can move the colorbar to the right, by resizing the space of all my subplots? Besides that i would like to enlarge the colorbar, to become a smooth closing with the top and bottom of all subplots.

Thanks for help and ideas.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: Ok, should be a verifiable example right now. :)

Comment: Specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23795901/5851928) answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`fig.subplots_adjust`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust) to set the bottom, top, left and right position of the subplots. Then use the same `bottom` and `top` to define where the colorbar is placed vertically. And make sure the left edge of the colorbar is to the right of the subplots.

Also, you can't use `tight_layout` here, otherwise it changes the positions.

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11.69,8.27), dpi=100)

bottom, top = 0.1, 0.9
left, right = 0.1, 0.8

fig.subplots_adjust(top=top, bottom=bottom, left=left, right=right, hspace=0.15, wspace=0.25)

for num in range(12):

    ax = fig.add_subplot(3,4,num+1)
    im = ax.scatter(np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10), 12, np.random.rand(10), cmap='magma')

fig.text(0.5, 0.02, 'x label', ha='center', fontsize=16)

fig.text(0.02, 0.5, 'ylabel ', va='center', rotation='vertical', fontsize=16)

cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.85, bottom, 0.05, top-bottom])
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax)

fig.savefig("example.pdf", dpi=fig.dpi, pad_inches=0.3)
```

[image]