# Using axes_grid1 without manipulating subplots

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, subplot

I'd like to draw a colorbar beside one of my subplots using `axes_grid1`.
The problem is, that the call of `make_axes_locatable` manipulates my subplot so that it doesn't have the same size of the other plots anymore.

Here is a minimal working example of my issue.

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(15,5))
_ax = ax[0,:].flatten('C')
values_x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
values_y = np.sin(values_x)
vmax = np.amax(values_x)
vmin = np.amin(values_x)
s = 1
ticks_rotation = 10
ticks_num = 5
_ax = ax[0,:].flatten('C')
plot_w = _ax[0].scatter(values_x, values_y, c=values_x, cmap='rainbow', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, s=s)
plot_v = _ax[1].scatter(values_x, values_y, c=values_x, cmap='rainbow', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, s=s)
_ax = ax[1,:].flatten('C')
plot_w = _ax[0].scatter(values_x, values_y, c=values_x, cmap='rainbow', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, s=s)
plot_v = _ax[1].scatter(values_x, values_y, c=values_x, cmap='rainbow', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, s=s)

divider = make_axes_locatable(_ax[1])
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)
v_delta = (vmax - vmin)*0.1
ticks = np.linspace(vmin+v_delta,vmax-v_delta,ticks_num)
cbar = fig.colorbar(plot_v, cax=cax, orientation='vertical', ticks=ticks)
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(np.around(ticks,decimals=1), rotation=ticks_rotation,rotation_mode='default')
plt.show()
```

[image]

What I want is actually all subplots of the same size with a nice color beside it.
Any suggestions?

Edit:
I really just want to have the colorbar besides the lower right subplot, and not like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar).

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html)? Specifically the function `demo_grid_with_single_cbar(fig)`

Comment: Yes, I already had a look at this but without any satisfactory results (or maybe it is me). Btw. I haven't found an explanation for `demo_grid_with_single_cbar` on this side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not attached to using `axes_grid1`, I personally prefer to use [a GridSpec](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) for this kind of jobs.

> **gridspec** is a module which specifies the location of the subplot in
>   the figure.
>
> [GridSpec](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html#matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec)
>
> specifies the geometry of the grid that a subplot will be placed. The number of rows and number of columns of the grid need to
>   be set. Optionally, the subplot layout parameters (e.g., left, right,
>   etc.) can be tuned.

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gs

gs0 = gs.GridSpec(2, 3, width_ratios=[20,20,1])
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[0,0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[0,1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[1,0])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[1,1])
cax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[:,2])


values_x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
values_y = np.sin(values_x)

for ax in [ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4]:
    plot_w = ax.scatter(values_x, values_y, c=values_x, cmap='rainbow', s=1)

cbar = fig.colorbar(plot_w, cax=cax, orientation='vertical')
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, but I just want to have it beside the lower right subplot. Is this also possible?

Comment: sure, change the definition of `cax` to `cax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[1,2])`

Comment: This looks great and does the jobs, thank!