# How to create multiple seaborn heatmaps with a shared legend in one figure?

Tags: python, seaborn

I want to create multiple (here: two) seaborn heatmaps in one figure where the heatmaps have different value ranges but should contain a single, shared legend.

The following code creates two heatmaps in a single figure, but the color-coding is different for the two plots.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,4)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([1., .5, .9, .6])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True)

sns_g = sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, yticklabels=True, ax=ax[0])
sns_g2 = sns.heatmap(df2, annot=True, cbar=False, ax=ax[1])

# fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.6)
# cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([1.1, 0.15, 0.05, .77])
# fig.colorbar(ax[1], cax=cbar_ax)

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

I included cbar=True in sns_g only to show that the two legends represent a different range. I want explicitly create two plots.

Comment: Highly relevant : [Matplotlib 2 Subplots, 1 Colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Thank you for the reference. However, I am not sure how to add a colormap in this case. If I uncomment the lines in my code, I get: AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'autoscale_None'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fig.colorbar` wants a `ScalarMappable` object, not an `Axes`. But seaborn's API let's you not worry about that.

According to its [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html?highlight=heatmap#seaborn.heatmap), which I found by searching for "heatmap" within seaborn.pydata.org, the function signature is:

```
seaborn.heatmap(data, vmin=None, vmax=None, cmap=None, center=None,
                robust=False, annot=None, fmt='.2g', annot_kws=None, 
                linewidths=0, linecolor='white', cbar=True, cbar_kws=None, 
                cbar_ax=None, square=False, xticklabels='auto',
                yticklabels='auto', mask=None, ax=None, **kwargs)
```

So all you need to do is pass the same `vmin` and `vmax` values to both heatmaps, but pass `cbar=False`, and `cbar=True` to the other.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to create the colorbar manually, you can preserve an axes in the grid for it. Use `vmin` and `vmax` to specify the limits, and use one of the heatmaps ( e.g. `axs[0].collections[0]`) as ScalarMappable input to `fig.colorbar`.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,4)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([1., .5, .9, .6])

vmin = min(df.values.min(), df2.values.min())
vmax = max(df.values.max(), df2.values.max())

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3, gridspec_kw=dict(width_ratios=[4,1,0.2]))

sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, cbar=False, ax=axs[0], vmin=vmin)
sns.heatmap(df2, annot=True, yticklabels=False, cbar=False, ax=axs[1], vmax=vmax)

fig.colorbar(axs[1].collections[0], cax=axs[2])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Little question: why you specify vim only for the first heatmap and vmax only for the second? (I tried specifying both values for both heatmaps and it didn't work well)