# How to share xaxis in contour-map-subplots which share a colorbar

Tags: matplotlib, subplot, colorbar, cartopy

I try to make 3 subplot which share one colorbar and the xaxis, as already explained by spinup in 
[Matplotlib 2 Subplots, 1 Colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar)

Using maps (with coastlines) in the subplots, it seems that a sharex is not supported.
However, is there a way, to apply a shared axis?

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.geoaxes import GeoAxes
from cartopy.mpl.ticker import LongitudeFormatter, LatitudeFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import AxesGrid
import numpy as np

def sample_data_3d(shape):
    """Returns `lons`, `lats`, `times` and fake `data`"""
    ntimes, nlats, nlons = shape
    lats = np.linspace(-np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, nlats)
    lons = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, nlons)
    lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
    wave = 0.75 * (np.sin(2 * lats) ** 8) * np.cos(4 * lons)
    mean = 0.5 * np.cos(2 * lats) * ((np.sin(2 * lats)) ** 2 + 2)

    lats = np.rad2deg(lats)
    lons = np.rad2deg(lons)
    data = wave + mean

    times = np.linspace(-1, 1, ntimes)
    new_shape = data.shape + (ntimes, )
    data = np.rollaxis(data.repeat(ntimes).reshape(new_shape), -1)
    data *= times[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]

    return lons, lats, times, data

def main():
    projection = ccrs.PlateCarree()
    axes_class = (GeoAxes,
                  dict(map_projection=projection))

    lons, lats, times, data = sample_data_3d((6, 73, 145))

    fig = plt.figure()
    axgr = AxesGrid(fig, 111, axes_class=axes_class,
                    nrows_ncols=(3, 1),
                    axes_pad=0.6,
                    share_all=True, #doesn't change anything
                    cbar_location='bottom',
                    cbar_mode='single',
                    cbar_pad=0.2,
                    cbar_size='3%',
                    label_mode='')  # note the empty label_mode

    for i, ax in enumerate(axgr):
        ax.coastlines()
        ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, zorder=100,              
                       edgecolor='k',facecolor='w')

        ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(-180, 180, 5), crs=projection)
        ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(-90, 90, 5), crs=projection)

    p = ax.contourf(lons, lats, data[i, ...],
                    transform=projection,
                    cmap='RdBu')

    axgr.cbar_axes[0].colorbar(p)

    plt.show()
```

Comment: The axes *are* shared. Can you go into detail what the exact problem is?

Comment: I'd just like to label the axis of the subplot at the bottom

Comment: `ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False)`?

Comment: Exactly the other way round, like:
subplot 1: x ticks without ticklabels
subplot 2: x ticks without ticklabels
subplot 3: x ticks with ticklabels

Comment: Is there anyone who knows that?

Comment: Knows what? You need to use `.tick_params(labelbottom=False)` to get rid of the labels as commented above.