# How to have only 1 shared colorbar for multiple plots

Tags: matplotlib

## Question

For multiple subplots to have a shared colorbar, please suggest a way.

I need one shared colorbar, but currently asymmetric plots get created which does not look nice.

```
%matplotlib inline
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.subplot(121)
plt.scatter(
    projected_3d[:, 0], 
    projected_3d[:, 1],
    c=y_train, 
    edgecolor='none', 
    alpha=0.5,
    cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('nipy_spectral', 10)
)
plt.xlabel('PC1')
plt.ylabel('PC2')
plt.colorbar(ax=plt.gca(), orientation="horizontal")

plt.subplot(122)
plt.scatter(
    projected_3d[:, 0], 
    projected_3d[:, 2],
    c=y_train, 
    edgecolor='none', 
    alpha=0.5,
    cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('nipy_spectral', 10)
)
plt.xlabel('PC1')
plt.ylabel('PC3')

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

### Update

Already answered in [Matplotlib 2 Subplots, 1 Colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar).

> **Using make_axes** is even easier and gives a better result. It also provides possibilities to customise the positioning of the colorbar. Also note the option of subplots to share x and y axes.

Without using make_axes, the layout gets corrupt.

Comment: Hi @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, they use "imshow" but in this case, it is plot which does not return path.

Comment: What *path* is it you're talking about? The question seems to be about the position of the colorbar, right? So it's the same for imshow and scatter.

Comment: As per OP statement, voting to close as Duplicate of [Matplotlib 2 Subplots, 1 Colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar)