# Create a common colorbar for multiple subplots in python

Tags: python, colorbar

I have divided a pandas dataframe in several subplots, as it is described in the following code. Every subplot has a specific colorbar. I want to make a common colorbar for all the subplots. The dataframe comes directly from an exel csv file.

```
Table_1_pos=df_pos.iloc[0:4,0:13]
Table_2_pos=df_pos.iloc[4:8,0:13]
Table_3_pos=df_pos.iloc[8:12,0:13]        
Table_4_pos=df_pos.iloc[12:16,0:13]        
[![enter image description here][1]][1]fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=4, gridspec_kw=dict(width_ratios=[4]),figsize=(15,8))  

ax1=sns.heatmap(Table_1_neg, annot=True, yticklabels=True, xticklabels=False, cbar=True, ax=axs[0], linewidths=1)
ax1.set_yticklabels(ax1.get_yticklabels(), rotation=0)
ax1.tick_params(right=True, left=False, labelright=True, labelleft=False)
bottom_1, top_1 = ax1.get_ylim()
ax1.set_ylim(bottom_1 + 0.5, top_1 - 0.5)
ax1.set_ylabel('Table 4')
ax1.set_ylabel(ax1.get_ylabel(),labelpad=20, rotation=0)        


ax2=sns.heatmap(Table_2_neg, annot=True, yticklabels=True, xticklabels=False, cbar=True, ax=axs[1], linewidths=1)
ax2.set_yticklabels(ax2.get_yticklabels(), rotation=0)
ax2.tick_params(right=True, left=False, labelright=True, labelleft=False)
bottom_2, top_2 = ax2.get_ylim()
ax2.set_ylim(bottom_2 + 0.5, top_2 - 0.5)
ax2.set_ylabel('Table 3')
ax2.set_ylabel(ax2.get_ylabel(),labelpad=20, rotation=0)         

ax3=sns.heatmap(Table_3_neg, annot=True, yticklabels=True, xticklabels=False, cbar=True, ax=axs[2], linewidths=1)
ax3.set_yticklabels(ax3.get_yticklabels(), rotation=0)
ax3.tick_params(right=True, left=False, labelright=True, labelleft=False)
bottom_3, top_3 = ax3.get_ylim()
ax3.set_ylim(bottom_3 + 0.5, top_3 - 0.5)
ax3.set_ylabel('Table 2')
ax3.set_ylabel(ax3.get_ylabel(),labelpad=20, rotation=0) 

ax4=sns.heatmap(Table_4_neg, annot=True, yticklabels=True, xticklabels=True, cbar=True, ax=axs[3], linewidths=1)
ax4.set_yticklabels(ax4.get_yticklabels(), rotation=0)
ax4.tick_params(right=True, left=False, labelright=True, labelleft=False)
bottom_4, top_4 = ax4.get_ylim()
ax4.set_ylim(bottom_1 + 0.5, top_1 - 0.5)        
ax4.set_ylabel('Table 1')
ax4.set_ylabel(ax4.get_ylabel(),labelpad=20, rotation=0) 


cbaxes = fig.add_axes([0.95, 0.1, 0.01, 0.8])     
mappable = axs.get_children()[0]         
plt.colorbar(mappable, ax = [ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4],orientation = 'vertical',cax = cbaxes)

plt.title("Tilt = {tilt}    -     WindDir = {winddir} (neg)  -   Cpnet,comparison".format(tilt=x, winddir=y),horizontalalignment='right',x=-30,y=1, verticalalignment='top')

out_fp_neg_1 = os.path.join(image_dirn, outpattern_neg.format(tilt=x, dir=y))
```

[image: Subplots with multiple colorbars]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your subplots use the same range of values, you can use the solution presented by [Joe Kington](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13784887/4373898).

However, from the image, it seems that all subplots do not have the same range.
Hopefully, `seaborn` allow you to define your heatmap minimum and maximum, as well as the axes on which to draw the colorbar.

Here is a working example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def main():
    df_pos = pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.random((16,13)) * 2 - 1
    )
    vmin = df_pos.min().min()
    vmax = df_pos.max().max()

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=1, figsize=(15,8))
    fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)
    cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.15, 0.05, 0.7])
    for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
        sns.heatmap(
            data=df_pos.iloc[4*i:4*(i+1), 0:13], ax=ax, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, cbar_ax=cbar_ax,
            xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, annot=True, linewidths=1)

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Alexis, the code you proposed its ideal for my case, but unfortunately i cannot use it, since it is not possible to convert a 13*16 dataframe in a numpy array. I did try a lot of times, but  always there was an error

Comment: @pantelis I don't see any problem while using a DataFrame. I updated with data coming from a dataframe instead of a numpy array.

Comment: Thank you very much