# add a single colourbar to multiple subplots in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

If I am generating the subplots in the way below, can I add a single colourbar for the whole figure?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(60,35))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,3,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,3,2)
ax3  = fig.add_subplot(2,3,3)
ax4  = fig.add_subplot(2,3,4)
ax5  = fig.add_subplot(2,3,5)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.05,wspace=0.05)
```

I have seen answers to similar questions on stackoverflow(e.g. [Matplotlib 2 Subplots, 1 Colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar)), but in those cases, the subplots are generated by something like

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
```

Currently, if I have to stick to my way of generating the subplots, how can I generate a single colourbar? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As in the [answer you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13784887/11743318) you just need to create an axis object to hold the colorbar:

```py
# e.g. from linked answer:
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.15, 0.05, 0.7])
#                change ^^^^  ^^^^  ^^^^  ^^^^ to suit your needs
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax)
```