# Adding a single colorbar to multiple healpy subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, healpy

I would like to add a custom `plt.colorbar` to a figure containing multiple `healpy` plots. I have found many posts on how to do this for the usual case of multiple `axes` objects, but the `healpy` makes it difficult.

I have the following MWE so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import healpy as hp

rows, cols = 8, 8
nplots = rows * cols
npix = 48
data = np.random.uniform(size=(nplots, npix))
fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(len(data)):
    hp.mollview(data[i, :], title='', cbar=False, fig=fig,
                sub=(rows, cols, i+1), margins=(0, 0, 0, 0),
                min=data.min(), max=data.max())

fig, ax = plt.gcf(), plt.gca()
image = ax.get_images()[0]
norm =  mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=data.min(), vmax=data.max())

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.new_vertical(size="5%", pad=0.7, pack_start=True)
fig.add_axes(cax)
fig.colorbar(image, cax=cax, norm=norm, orientation='horizontal',
             label='colorbar')
plt.show()
```

[See the erroneous plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lhJN.png)

As shown in the linked image I end up with a `colorbar` attached to the last `ax` rather than the entire `fig`. I would like a simple `colorbar` on the bottom (or right side) of the `fig`, with a range specified through `Normalize` as above. Again, it is the fact that I am using `healpy` to produce the figure that rules out the usual solutions, at least to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have healpy installed, but probably this library just creates its own axes. The code below emulates such a situation. You can get the axes from `fig.axes`.
As in [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/colorbar_placement.html), a default colorbar can be placed just by giving a list of all the 'axes' (an `ax` is more or less matplotlib's name for a subplot): `plt.colorbar(im, ax=fig.axes)`. If the colorbar would be too large, it has a `shrink=0.6` parameter.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 6))

nrows = 4
ncols = 6
for i in range(1, nrows + 1):
    for j in range(1, ncols + 1):
        plt.subplot(nrows, ncols, (i - 1) * ncols + j, projection="mollweide")
        arr = np.random.rand(18, 36)
        Lon, Lat = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 36 + 1), np.linspace(-np.pi / 2., np.pi / 2., 18 + 1))
        plt.pcolormesh(Lon, Lat, arr, cmap=plt.cm.hot)
im = fig.axes[0].collections[0] # or fig.axes[0].get_images()[0] when created as image
plt.colorbar(im, ax=fig.axes)

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Note that in your code, `fig` already points to the current figure, making `fig = plt.gcf()` unnecessary.  `ax = plt.gca()` indicates the `ax` that was last active. In the case of the example plot this seems to be the lower right one. So, this helps to find an example image, but not to position the colorbar next to all subplots.

If you need more control about the colorbar placement, you can also adopt the approach from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar):

```py
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.85)
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.90, 0.15, 0.03, 0.7])
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax)
```

Comment: This works well, thanks! I had to use the second suggestion of `im = fig.axes[0].get_images()[0]`, since `fig.axes[0]` has type `healpy.projaxes.HpxMollweideAxes` but `fig.axes[0].collections` is an empty list.