# Colorbar for Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter

Im trying to use a colorbar for multiple subplot, with screenshots attached. The colorbar would be for a column named 'age' in each of these graphs. I would like the colorbar to be on the right hand side.[image: Code with resulting graphs]

[image]

Comment: See also [Matplotlib 2 Subplots, 1 Colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar)

Comment: There is always the docs: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/colorbar_placement.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-colorbar-placement-py