# One colorbar to indicate data range for multiple subplots using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, colorbar

I have saw many similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar). However, the colorbar actually indicates the data range of last subplot, as is verified by the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(19680801)


fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1)
cmaps = ['RdBu_r', 'viridis']
for row in range(2):
    ax = axs[row]
    if row == 0:
        pcm = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.random((20, 20)) * (-100),
                            cmap=cmaps[0])
    elif row == 1:
            pcm = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.random((20, 20)) * 100,
                            cmap=cmaps[0])
fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=axs)
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

The colobar only indicates the data range of second sub-figure. The data in the first sub-figure is actually negative, which is not shown in the colorbar.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1)
cmaps = ['RdBu_r', 'viridis']
for row in range(2):
    ax = axs[row]
    if row == 0:
        pcm = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.random((20, 20)) * (-100),
                            cmap=cmaps[0])
    elif row == 1:
            pcm = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.random((20, 20)) * 100,
                            cmap=cmaps[0])
    fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image: output]

So how to make one colorbar shared by multiple subplots to indicate overall data range ?

The problem may be cause by `fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=axs)`, where `pcm` is pointed to the second sub-figure, but I am not sure how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the color limits to be the same...

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1)
cmaps = ['RdBu_r', 'viridis']
for row in range(2):
    ax = axs[row]
    mult = -100 if row == 0 else 100
    pcm = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.random((20, 20)) * mult,
                            cmap=cmaps[0], vmin=-150, vmax=150)
fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=axs)
plt.show()
```

or equivalently you can specify a Normalize object:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 


fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1)
cmaps = ['RdBu_r', 'viridis']
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=-150, vmax=150)
for row in range(2):
    ax = axs[row]
    mult = -100 if row == 0 else 100
    pcm = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.random((20, 20)) * mult,
                            cmap=cmaps[0], norm=norm)
fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=axs)
plt.show()
```

Comment: mmm while I think this works code-wise, it produces deceiving figures. The colors in the figures seem to only be comparable in as much as they are within the same range (after normalization), but you lose the relationship between them, which is often the whole point of having a shared colorbar. I blame matplotlib, it should not be possible to plot different colorbars for different subplots. I wonder how many papers with misleading colorbars there are around

Comment: @Euler_Salter - I'm not following your concern.  The user should of course specify individual colorbars if the norms are different between subplots. The original user specifically asked how to make the colormapping (norm) identical between axes.