# Why color bar in matplotlib showing inconsistent value for 2 my figures

Tags: python

When I plot fig. A with only 1 map the highest value at colorbar is 140, but adding 2 other plots (different its time variable) it become 64. It means that value 140 is gone from the map1, why?? it is a bug?

A colorbar of multi-plot should exactly cover all range of values of all the plots.

Any suggestions?
thanks

A.
[image]

B. [image]

Comment: It looks like that cbar only take into account the last map.

Comment: You need to provide the code, so others can help without guessing.

Comment: I found later: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67165630/one-colorbar-to-indicate-data-range-for-multiple-subplots-using-matplotlib