# United color bar for all subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I'm trying to add a color bar to my plot, which contains 4 subplots.
I've added the subplots manually using this code:

```
extent = [-8, 37, 28, 46]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5.5, 3.5), constrained_layout= False)
spec = fig.add_gridspec(ncols=2, nrows=2)
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0, 0], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(), frameon= False)
ax0.set_extent(extent)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0, 0], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(), frameon= False)
ax1.set_extent(extent)
```

I wrote these lines up to ax3.
Now that I try to make a color bar, using `plt.color bar()`

It adds a color bar only to the last subplot... I've tried other online solutions, but they all use the `fig, axes= plt.subplots(...)` which I don't use..

**edit**- this question [How to have one colorbar for all subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/how-to-have-one-colorbar-for-all-subplots) doesn't really help me...
when I try to run this code

`fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)`

`cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.15, 0.05, 0.7])`

`fig.colorbar(ax3, cax=cbar_ax)`

I get this error-
AttributeError: 'GeoAxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'get_array'
I'm using Cartopy to make a hist2d of global occurrences.

Does anyone have an idea how to overcome this?
Thanks in advance,
Karin.

Comment: I find this answer to be very helpful. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/how-to-have-one-colorbar-for-all-subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/how-to-have-one-colorbar-for-all-subplots)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have one colorbar for all subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/how-to-have-one-colorbar-for-all-subplots)

Comment: when I run this in my code -   
  fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)
    cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.15, 0.05, 0.7])
    fig.colorbar(ax3, cax=cbar_ax)
it gives me this error- AttributeError: 'GeoAxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'get_array'

I guess it's important to say I'm using cartopy?

Comment: Sorry! I'm new here... added it in my question

Comment: Colorbar does not take an axes as an argument.  We can't help you without a complete example, but the argument to colorbar is usually a ScalarMappable, which will be returned to you by whatever you are colormapping.  Please read https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/colorbar_placement.html

Comment: I don't think I understand what other information is needed...

Comment: I use a lot of dataframes so it's quite difficult to add them or their code here. 
I just need help understanding how when you create subplots manually (without axes) can you create a united color bar

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem... just used `fig, axes =plt.subplots(...)`  and converted my code to use this code :-)