# Matplotlib - Tight layout of multiple subplots with colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a series of subplots in a single row, all sharing the same colorbar and I would like to use `plt.tight_layout()`.

However when used naively, the colorbar messes everything up. Luckily, I found this in the matplotlib documentation, but it works only for one subplot.

## Minimal Working Example

I tried to adapt it to multiple subplots but the subplot to which the colorbar is assigned to ends up being smaller.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np

plt.close('all')
arr = np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(8, 4))
im0 = ax[0].imshow(arr, interpolation="none")
im1 = ax[1].imshow(arr, interpolation='none')

divider = make_axes_locatable(plt.gca())
cax = divider.append_axes("right", "5%", pad="3%")
plt.colorbar(im0, cax=cax)

plt.tight_layout()
```

This is what the result looks like.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share what you wish to achieve by using `plt.tight_layout`?

Comment: @medium-dimensional good question. Basically I want the overall figure to have tight subplots meaning that the horizontal and vertical spaces are reduced. But I would like this to happen even if there's a colorbar: the horizontal space between all subplots and the colorbar is the same.


However, I am also happy if the horizontal space between the right most subplot and the colorbar is smaller than that between plots, as long as all plots stay at the same size

Comment: To summarize:

1) all subplots to have the same size (vertical and horizontal)
2) colorbar to have same height as plots
3) being able to control spacing between plots

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38940369/7789963

Comment: And also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45634754/7789963

Answer (score 5):

With the newest matplotlib (3.6), there is a new option `layout='compressed'` for this situation:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(4, 2), layout='compressed')
im0 = ax[0].imshow(arr)
im1 = ax[1].imshow(arr)

plt.colorbar(im0, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]