# Multiple panels with a common colorbar using divider.append_axes option

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am trying to add one colorbar common to 4 panels. The answers I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/how-to-have-one-colorbar-for-all-subplots) were good but unfortunately not entirely useful to me. The main challenge I was facing in these methods was the adjustment of colorbar width, height, distance from the panels and the spacing among the panels themselves.

Given below is the code I am now using. In the current output, the figure size, placement of panels, spacing and bar width is exactly as I want except for the **bar height** and the **top right panel**. Can anyone help me on how to make the bar as high as the top panel's upper edge and correct the top right panel placement?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

arr = np.random.random((4,10,10))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, sharex=True,sharey=True, figsize=(10.1,10))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.04, bottom=0.1, right=0.96, top=0.9, wspace=-0.2, hspace=0.01)

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        c = axes[i,j].imshow(arr[2*i+j,:,:].T, cmap='cool',aspect='equal',origin='lower')
        axes[i,j].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', length=5, width=1, labelsize=20,direction='in')
        axes[i,j].tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', length=3, width=1,direction='in')
        axes[i,j].minorticks_on()
        axes[i,j].yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
        axes[i,j].xaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
        axes[i,j].set_aspect(1.0/axes[i,j].get_data_ratio(), adjustable='box')


divider = make_axes_locatable(axes[1,1])
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
cb=plt.colorbar(c,cax)
cb.set_label(r'$x/y$',fontsize=16)
cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=16)

plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

[image: See output plot here]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have one colorbar for all subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/how-to-have-one-colorbar-for-all-subplots)

Comment: I am afraid not. In these methods, I lose the ability to choose my desired spacing and bar width.

Comment: It's already a month that I've posted an answer, but you gave me not any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different options. I suggest using [`AxesGrid`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_grid.ImageGrid.html)

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import AxesGrid

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 6))
grid = AxesGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(2,2), axes_pad=0.25,
                cbar_size="6%", cbar_location="right", cbar_mode="single")
images = [ax.imshow([[1, 2], [3, 4]]) for ax in grid.axes_all]
cbar = plt.colorbar(images[0], cax=grid.cbar_axes[0])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Sorry. @gboffi I completely forgot. Your solution worked for me.

Comment: @DrMittal If my answer solved your problem, you may consider accepting it.