How to get the surface plot and color bar values to be the same in two different plots
I have two original plots, #1: original data
And #2: Fitted data
I would like the colors in the two plots to correspond. Meaning, the flat zero-value regions outside of the peaks are the same color, and other values (i.e., where f(x,y)=0.5) have the same color in both plots.
Here is some of my code:
# set up data
asdi_cb_merged = signalMatrix_FPI.ravel()
asdi_cb_merged_positive = np.abs(asdi_cb_merged)
valmin, valmax = np.min(asdi_cb_merged), np.max(asdi_cb_merged)

# define plotting sequence
def plot_data(x, y, data, title): #valmin, valmax, 
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
    surface = ax.plot_surface(x, y, data.reshape(data_points, data_points), cmap=cm.viridis) #, vmin=valmin, vmax=valmax
    fig.colorbar(surface, shrink=0.5, aspect=20, cmap=cm.viridis, pad=0.07)
    ax.view_init(elev=10, azim=30)  
    plt.show()
    return

# Plot the original data 
plot_data(x, y, asdi_cb_merged, 'title') #, valmin, valmax

# Do the (curve) fitting:
x_max = np.where(asdi_cb_merged.reshape(data_points,data_points)==np.max(asdi_cb_merged.reshape(data_points,data_points)))[1][0]
y_max = np.where(asdi_cb_merged.reshape(data_points,data_points)==np.max(asdi_cb_merged.reshape(data_points,data_points)))[0][0]
iGuess = (11, x_max, y_max, 10, 0, 1) # Amp, xy, yx, sigma, theta, offset
lower_upper_bounds = ((0, 0, 0, 1, -np.inf, -np.inf), (np.inf, 200, 200, 45, np.inf, np.inf))
popt, pcov = curve_fit(twoD_Gaussian, (x, y), asdi_cb_merged, p0=iGuess, bounds=lower_upper_bounds)
data_fitted = twoD_Gaussian((x, y), *popt)

# Plot the fitted data
plot_data(x, y, data_fitted, 'Fitted Data') #, valmin, valmax

I thought by putting in the valmin and valmax variables for the first plot, I would get equal colors for equal values Ithe second; instead, I got one color in both plots for all values. Like this:
Monochromatic color values #1
And
Monochromatic color values #2
Do you know how I can fix this?
I tried putting the commented out valmin & valmax terms into the code above. The 2nd set of images resulted.

This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/how-to-have-one-colorbar-for-all-subplots

The valmin, valmax you used for your last two images are much too far apart. Something like valmin = -0.25; valmax=0.25 would be closer to your original colors. Note that the code in your post is not reproducible, with a lot of missing values (starting with x and y).
