# subplot matplotlib wrong syntax

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, outofrangeexception, subplot

I am using matplotlib to subplot in a loop. For instance, i would like to subplot 49 data sets, and from the doc, i implemented it this way;

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X1=list(range(0,10000,1))
X1 = [ x/float(10) for x in X1 ]
nb_mix = 2

parameters = []

for i in range(49):

    param = []

    Y = [0] * len(X1)

    for j in range(nb_mix):

        mean = 5* (1 + (np.random.rand() * 2 - 1 ) * 0.5 )
        var = 10* (1 + np.random.rand() * 2 - 1 )
        scale = 5* ( 1 + (np.random.rand() * 2 - 1) * 0.5 )

        Y = [ Y[k] + scale * np.exp(-((X1[k] - mean)/float(var))**2) for k in range(len(X1)) ] 
        param = param + [[mean, var, scale]]



    ax = plt.subplot(7, 7, i + 1)
    ax.plot(X1, Y)

    parameters = parameters + [param]

ax.show()
```

However, i have an index out of range error from i=0 onwards.

Where can i do better to have it works ?

-- this is the error i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\WORK\SOLVEUR\ALGOCODE\PYTHON_\DataSets\DataSets_DONLP2_gaussians.py", line 167, in <module>
    ax = plt.subplot(7, 7, i + 1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 766, in subplot
    a = fig.add_subplot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 777, in add_subplot
    a = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 8364, in __init__
    self._subplotspec = GridSpec(rows, cols)[int(num)-1]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\gridspec.py", line 175, in __getitem__
    raise IndexError("index out of range")
IndexError: index out of range
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post the complete error message.

Comment: for me it works when I change the last line to plt.show()...

Comment: `range(len(X1))` is almost never what you want to do. Either use `X1`, or `enumerate(X1)`

Comment: @BrenBarn this is the error i got

Comment: @RaphaelRoth it is not for me..., added error message

Comment: It also works for me with out error.  You might also want to look into doing something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046127/matplotlib-very-slow-is-it-normal/13060980#13060980 given your large number of sub-plots.

Comment: what version of matplotlib are you using?  I am wondering if this is an old bug.